# What does "nonlocal" do in Python 3?

Tags: python, closures, global, nested-function, python-nonlocal

What does `nonlocal` do in Python 3.x?

---

<sub>To close debugging questions where OP needs `nonlocal` and doesn't realize it, please use [Is it possible to modify variable in python that is in outer, but not global, scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947) instead.</sub>

<sub>Although Python 2 is [officially unsupported as of January 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), if for some reason you are forced to maintain a Python 2.x codebase and need an equivalent to `nonlocal`, see [nonlocal keyword in Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190706).</sub>

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414304/local-functions-in-python

Comment: Here is the official Python website documentation for nonlocal: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement (this documentation has been available since Python 3.0, so the OP's assertion that there is no official documentation was just wrong)

Comment: `"There is no documentation for nonlocal".` Actually, you can do `help(keyword_in_string)` for documentations in Python 3 and above

Comment: To be fair the official docs kind of suck on the subject. The selected answer's example makes things very clear, making this a valuable question.

Comment: In the official Python tutorial there is a [good explanation of the concept of scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) with a [nice example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example).

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example) is the official documentation with example, and makes things pretty clear.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why do you think the docs "suck"? Genuinely curious. I found `help('nonlocal')` to be pretty clear.

Comment: @EntangledLoops. I suspect that it was not so more than 5 years ago when I made that comment?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I might have thought that too, but there is an answer from about 9 years ago below that copy/pasted the text, and it looks the same as it appears today.

Comment: @EntangledLoops. Also, I didn't know much five years ago

Comment: Note for duplicate closers: This question explains what `nonlocal` does. For the reverse situation - OP needs `nonlocal` and doesn't realize it - consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947 instead.

Answer (score 657, accepted):

Compare this, without using `nonlocal`:

```
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# inner: 2
# outer: 1
# global: 0
```

To this, using **`nonlocal`**, where `inner()`'s `x` is now also `outer()`'s `x`:

```
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# inner: 2
# outer: 2
# global: 0
```

If we were to use **`global`**, it would bind `x` to the properly "global" value:

```
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        global x
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)
        
    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# inner: 2
# outer: 1
# global: 2
```

Comment: Its very similar - but note that the outer x is not global in the example but is instead defined in the outer function.

Comment: so it lets you do inner classes that reference outer vars, like java?

Comment: @Dustin - Actually, if you had class A with an attribute x and a subclass B defined in it, you would refer to x from within B as A.x

Comment: Yes, Java inner classes have similar behaviour.

Comment: The code easily gets heavily indented when defining inner functions and ends up violating the 79 chars PEP8 recommendation. Any way to get around this problem? Can an inner function somehow be placed outside the outer function? I know the question sounds stupid, but I'm earnest.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen you could pass the function as an arg that's the beauty of higher order functions.
Also in functional programming this is called composition, python is not a pure FP language but you can certainly play with a features (generators, higher order functions are some examples)

Comment: so in essence the rule of thumb it to use `nonlocal` when an inner function will try to modify one of its closures?

Comment: What if there are 3 nested functions? Is there a way to access all 4 levels from within the innermost function then?

Comment: It seems objects, such as arrays and dictionaries, work differently. They are nonlocal by default. Is that correct? What if I want to them local?

Comment: why name 3 variables in difference scopes, **with same name**? just to use `nonlocal`?i'd rather take a different name and avoid `nonlocal`. is there any benefit or something inevitable here?

Comment: @LeiYang `nonlocal` is required in order to modify the "outer" `x`, *even if there is no* global `x`. Both `global` and `nonlocal` *prevent* `x` from being a local variable in `inner` - in these cases, it is *not actually* a separate variable.

Answer (score 129):

In short, it lets you assign values to a variable in an outer (but non-global) scope.  See [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 56):

A google search for "python nonlocal" turned up the Proposal, [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/), which fully describes the syntax and reasoning behind the statement.  in short, it works in exactly the same way as the `global` statement, except that it is used to refer to variables that are neither global nor local to the function.

Here's a brief example of what you can do with this.  The counter generator can be rewritten to use this so that it looks more like the idioms of languages with closures.

```
def make_counter():
    count = 0
    def counter():
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        return count
    return counter
```

Obviously, you could write this as a generator, like:

```
def counter_generator():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        yield count
```

*But* while this is perfectly idiomatic python, it seems that the first version would be a bit more obvious for beginners.  Properly using generators, by calling the returned function, is a common point of confusion.  The first version explicitly returns a function.

Comment: I was sure that's what the keyword 'global' does - works up higher enviornments until it reaches a variable with that name. a variable x could be declared at module level, inside a class, then separately in a function inside this class and then in an inner function of that function - how does it know which x to refer to?

Comment: the thing about global is that it only works for global variables.  it cannot see variables in an enclosing, nonglobal scope.

Comment: I tried the make_counter - however it doesn't return a generator but a function. is there a way to return a generator so later i could iterate over it?

Comment: @Dejel: this example is intended to illustrate the `nonlocal` statement in Python;  If you want a sequence of natural numbers, the python idiom is actually [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools#itertools.count)

Comment: I would like to demo the ability to return a generator like with yield - yield actually returns a generator. My idea is not to use yield and instead maybe use nonlocal or another solution

Comment: @Dejel: It sounds like you're having a problem that's a bit different from the one ooboo asked about.  Please ask a new question instead of using the comments section here.

Comment: I think it is misleading to say, `it works in exactly the same way as the global statement`. Because `global x` can create a new global variable `x` if if did not existed, but `nonlocal x` must refer to an existing x variable in the enclosing scope.

Comment: @ooboo "I was sure that's what the keyword 'global' does - works up higher enviornments until it reaches a variable with that name" No; it looks *only* at the *global* scope (and builtins, if you consider those separate), not in any intermediate scopes. Looking up a *local* will consider enclosing scopes, but anything not found locally will be *read-only*.

Answer (score 24):

It takes the one "closest" to the point of reference in the source code.
This is called "Lexical Scoping" and is standard for >40 years now.

Python's class members are really in a dictionary called `__dict__` and will never be reached by lexical scoping.

If you don't specify `nonlocal` but do `x = 7`, it will create a new local variable "x".
If you do specify `nonlocal`, it will find the "closest" "x" and assign to that.
If you specify `nonlocal` and there is no "x", it will give you an error message.

The keyword `global` has always seemed strange to me since it will happily ignore all the other "x" except for the outermost one.

Comment: Note that if you _don't_ assign a new value, and instead only read it (e.g. `print(x)`), lexical scoping is the default and `nonlocal` makes no difference.

Comment: "The keyword global has always seemed strange to me since it will happily ignore all the other "x" except for the outermost one." I don't understand the reasoning. The outermost scope is global; the other ones are not. Why would `global` access them?

Answer (score 17):

> help('nonlocal')
>   The `nonlocal` statement
>
> ---
>
> ```
>     nonlocal_stmt ::= "nonlocal" identifier ("," identifier)*
> ```
>
> The `nonlocal` statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
>   previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope.  This is
>   important because the default behavior for binding is to search the
>   local namespace first.  The statement allows encapsulated code to
>   rebind variables outside of the local scope besides the global
>   (module) scope.
>
> Names listed in a `nonlocal` statement, unlike to those listed in a
>   `global` statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an
>   enclosing scope (the scope in which a new binding should be created
>   cannot be determined unambiguously).
>
> Names listed in a `nonlocal` statement must not collide with pre-
>   existing bindings in the local scope.
>
> See also:
>
> **PEP 3104** - Access to Names in Outer Scopes
>         The specification for the `nonlocal` statement.
>
> Related help topics: global, NAMESPACES

Source: [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)

Comment: Learn something new every day. I had no idea you could use `help()` on keywords (and now my mind is blown: `help()` with no arguments goes _interactive_).

Answer (score 13):

Quote from the [Python 3 Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal):

> The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding globals.

As said in the reference, in case of several nested functions only variable in the nearest enclosing function is modified:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        def innermost():
            nonlocal x
            x = 3

        x = 2
        innermost()
        if x == 3: print('Inner x has been modified')

    x = 1
    inner()
    if x == 3: print('Outer x has been modified')

x = 0
outer()
if x == 3: print('Global x has been modified')

# Inner x has been modified
```

The "nearest" variable can be several levels away:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        def innermost():
            nonlocal x
            x = 3

        innermost()

    x = 1
    inner()
    if x == 3: print('Outer x has been modified')

x = 0
outer()
if x == 3: print('Global x has been modified')

# Outer x has been modified
```

But it cannot be a global variable:

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        def innermost():
            nonlocal x
            x = 3

        innermost()

    inner()

x = 0
outer()
if x == 3: print('Global x has been modified')

# SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 0    #1. global variable with respect to every function in program

def f():
    a = 0          #2. nonlocal with respect to function g
    def g():
        nonlocal a
        a=a+1
        print("The value of 'a' using nonlocal is ", a)
    def h():
        global a               #3. using global variable
        a=a+5
        print("The value of a using global is ", a)
    def i():
        a = 0              #4. variable separated from all others
        print("The value of 'a' inside a function is ", a)

    g()
    h()
    i()
print("The value of 'a' global before any function", a)
f()
print("The value of 'a' global after using function f ", a)
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal understanding of the "nonlocal" statement (and do excuse me as I am new to Python and Programming in general) is that the "nonlocal" is a way to use the Global functionality within iterated functions rather than the body of the code itself. A Global statement between functions if you will.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) says below:

> The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
> previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding
> globals. ...

So for example, `nonlocal foo` in `inner()` can access **the non-local variable `foo = 10`** in `middle()` but not **the non-local variable `foo = 5`** in `outer()` or **the global variable `foo = 0`** outside `outer()` as shown below:

```py
foo = 0 # <- ✖
def outer():
    foo = 5 # <- ✖
    def middle():
        foo = 10 # <- 〇
        def inner():
            nonlocal foo # Here
            foo += 1
            print(foo) # 11
        inner()
    middle()
outer()
```

Answer (score 0):

with 'nonlocal' inner functions(ie;nested inner functions) can get read & '***write***' permission *for that specific variable of the outer parent function*. And nonlocal can be used only inside inner functions
eg:

```
a = 10
def Outer(msg):
    a = 20
    b = 30
    def Inner():
        c = 50
        d = 60
        print("MU LCL =",locals())
        nonlocal a
        a = 100
        ans = a+c
        print("Hello from Inner",ans)       
        print("value of a Inner : ",a)
    Inner()
    print("value of a Outer : ",a)

res = Outer("Hello World")
print(res)
print("value of a Global : ",a)
```