# How to replace Python function while supporting all passed in parameters

Tags: python, decorator, keyword-argument

I'm looking for a way to decorate an arbitrary python function, so that an alternate function is called instead of the original, with all parameters passed as a list or dict.

More precisely, something like this (where f is any function, and replacement_f takes a list and a dict):

```
def replace_func(f, replacement_f):
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        replacement_f(args, kwargs)
    return new_f
```

However, I cannot reference `replacement_f` inside `new_f`.  And I can't use the standard trick of passing `replacement_f` to `new_f` as the default for a different parameter, because I'm using the `*args` and `**kwargs` variable argument lists.

The location where the original function is called cannot change, and will accept both positional and named parameters.

I fear that isn't very clear, but I'm happy to clarify if needed.

Thanks

Comment: you are right: this is not clear. i think you don't need to change the call of the original function, but rather its definition. if you can't change that, you probably can't decorate it either.

Comment: thanks all.  I was making this far too difficult, I can just replace the function without all the *args, **kwargs hassle.

Also, I think the scope rules have changed since Python 1.x, now I can reference a variable from the outer function inside the inner function definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you just try:

```
f = replacement_f
```

*example*:

```
>>> def rep(*args):
    print(*args, sep=' -- ')

>>> def ori(*args):
    print(args)

>>> ori('dfef', 32)
('dfef', 32)
>>> ori = rep
>>> ori('dfef', 32)
dfef -- 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I think SilentGhost's answer is the best solution if it works for you, for the sake of completeness, here is the correct version of what you where trying to do:

To define a decorator that takes an argument, you have to introduce an additional level:

```
def replace_function(repl):
    def deco(f):
        def inner_f(*args, **kwargs):
            repl(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner_f
    return deco
```

Now you can use the decorator with an argument:

```
@replace_function(replacement_f)
def original_function(*args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

Comment: that's how a decorator is applied to a function.

Comment: thanks, hop.  that's closer to what i was thinking originally

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to pass all arguments from one function to another.

Simply do:

```
def replace_func(f, replacement_f):
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        replacement_f(*args, **kwargs) # args & kwargs will be expanded
    return new_f
```

Answer (score 0):

does this do what you mean?  Untested

```
def replace_func(f, replacement_f):
    nonlocal replacement_f  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<py3k magic
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        replacement_f(*args, **kwargs) # args & kwargs will be expanded
    replacement_f = new_f
```

[Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)

edit: its a start, im confused exactly what you want, but i think nonlocal will help