# Python's nonlocal depends on level of hierarchy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, closures

This question is a follow-up on [a question about Python variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370357/923794). Additional questions [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1261875/923794), [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414304/923794) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009402/read-write-python-closures/2009899#2009899) can be found on SO, among even more.
The official [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement), and [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) are supposed to explain the details, but they don't seem fully self-explanatory to me.

The topic I'm trying to solve is refactoring of code containing `nonlocal`/`global` by moving that code up/down one level of hierarchy.

What I do not understand are the implications of this sentence from the Python reference:

> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike to those listed in a
>   global statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing
>   scope (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be
>   determined unambiguously).

Given the following code on global scope:

```
var = 0
def outer():
    global var                  # line A
    var = 1
    def inner():
        nonlocal var            # line B
        var = 2

        print('inner:', var)

    inner()
    print('outer:', var)

outer()
print('main:', var)
```

Execution raises an error:

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'var' found
```

The code works (with different semantics, of course, if either line A is commented out:

```
inner: 2
outer: 2
main: 0
```

or line B is commented out:

```
inner: 2
outer: 1
main: 1
```

However, in the above example, and since `nonlocal` is supposed to bind var to the "enclosing scope", I would have expected that line A binds the outer/var into global scope and line B then looks for outer/var and also rebinds inner/var to global/var. Instead it seems to not find it at all (due to the rebinding in line A, I suppose) and raise an error.

The desired result I expected was:

```
inner: 2
outer: 2
main: 2
```

Is this just one more example of the confusing state of mind of scoping in Python?

Or, to make this a constructive question:

- How can such an example be written in a way that it does not matter at which level a function resides (having to exchange `global` with `nonlocal` and vice versa)?
- If the functions reside at an intermediate, and unknown level of hierarchy, how could the author of `outer()` change the code that neither the outermost (in this case global) level, nor the `inner()` level have to be touched? -

In my humble understanding of the language, constructs like these (dependecies on closures) are just to be avoided. Others already have suggested to use other language features ([classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009402/read-write-python-closures/2009474#2009474), [func attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009402/read-write-python-closures/2009575#2009575)) to achieve this kind of context sensitivity.

Comment: Global and local variables are fundamentally different in Python.  `nonlocal` statements can only refer to local variables of an enclosing scope and never to global variables -- that's what `global` is for after all.  The concepts behind `global` and `nonlocal` are rather different.  Your arguments how the current state should pose a problem are entirely constructed.  My answer would be: Don't use global variables, and don't use `global`, and all mentioned "problems" (and a few more) will be gone.

Comment: While I generally agree to avoid using globals, others seem to find the concept so useful that Python provides the `global` keyword and Py3k even added a `nonlocal`. I'm trying to understand the implications of their combined use.

Comment: "… and Py3k even added a `nonlocal`."  `nonlocal` is meant to make closures more useful.  It is unrelated to global variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Python's nonlocal keyword like the global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873615/why-doesnt-pythons-nonlocal-keyword-like-the-global-scope)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`global` and `nonlocal` are not meant to be combined.  They mean different things:

- `global` means the name exists at the module level
- `nonlocal` means the name exists in an outer lexical function scope

The reason you are getting the original exception is because you told Python that `var` is nonlocal (meaning it is in an outer function definition), but there is **no function-level binding** for `var` in any outer function definition because you told Python in the outer function that `var` was global.

Comment: "global and nonlocal are not meant to be combined" and that's exactly my problem: If not, then refactoring of code is made more difficult. Given that an innermost function uses a `nonlocal` and the immediate surrounding function as well. If the surrounding function changes the binding to `global`, then the innermost function must be changed, too. But, alas, with the syntax at hand I don't see another way. (But to use class wrappers and such)

Comment: I see your point, but it does not seem to me to be an unreasonable amount of work if you are refactoring closures into non-closures.

Answer (score 0):

> How can such an example be written in a way that it does not matter at
>   which level a function resides (having to exchange global with
>   nonlocal and vice versa)?

It does not matter at which level a function resides. It only matters at which level the variable resides.

> If the functions reside at an intermediate, and unknown level of
>   hierarchy, how could the author of outer() change the code that
>   neither the outermost (in this case global) level, nor the inner()
>   level have to be touched?

You are asking whether it is possible for a function at an intermediate level to, by changing something in its code, to cause a variable in an inner function to alternately change something at a global scope or something in the outer function's local scope. This seems like a really weird thing to be able to do.

Comment: My point is about refactoring: If the middle function together with its inner function is moved one level lower, a `nonlocal` would have to be changed in `global`, even if its immediate surrounding function would also make use of the variable. Hm, I start to think I've chosen a bad example for detailing the problem I have with this syntax/scoping.

Comment: @cfi I just want to make sure I understand what you mean by: "If the middle function together with its inner function is moved one level lower". Initially, both `var` and `outer` are inside another function's block, therefore both `outer` and `inner` use `nonlocal var`. By moving the "middle function together with its inner function one level lower" you mean moving both `var` and `outer` closer to the global scope? And if this new scope for `var` and `outer` were the global scope, you would have to change both the `nonlocal var` in `outer` and in `inner` to `global var`?