# Why am I able to global a non-existing variable in python

Tags: python, global

First, I fully understand what `global` statement means and how to use.

Now, let's look at this:

```
x = 100
def f():
    global x
    global xxx
    x = 99
    return x

print(f())
# >>> 99
print(x)
# >>> 99
```

You can see that by using `global x`, I successfully changed the value of x in the global environment.

But `xxx` does not exist at all, why am I allowed to global it and it won't even bring any error even if the function is executed?

Comment: I THINK that `global xxx` is just a redundant statement but since its a valid python code the python interpreter merely ignores it like a mother ignores your childish mistakes. I could be wrong though.

Comment: But I thought python check all the variable bounding situation in compiling before running at all, and if there is a bounding error, then it won't execute?

Comment: You can initialize variables with `global` by just giving them a name, although I am not sure what the default behavior is for these variables. Oddly enough I cannot find anything in the Python 3 docs about the `global` keyword and its use.

Comment: I amend my previous statement: you are allowed to declare globals with a naked `global x`, but you can't access them if you haven't assigned anything to them. I think the interpreter just throws this out and ignores it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`global x` does not define, declare, or otherwise create `x`. It simply states that if and when `x` is assigned to in the current function scope (whether that assignment comes before or after the `global` statement, which is why it is strongly recommended that `global` statements be used at the beginning of the function), the assignment is made to a global variable of that name, not a local variable. The actual creation is still the job of an actual assignment.

Put another way, `global` doesn't generate any byte code by itself; it simply modifies what byte code other assignment statements might generate. Consider these two functions:

```
def f():
    global x
    x = 99

def g():
    x = 99
```

The only difference in the byte code for these two functions is that `f` use `STORE_GOBAL` as a result of the `global` statement, while `g` uses `STORE_FAST`.

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (99)
              3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(g)
  8           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (99)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you were to add an "unused" `global` statement, such as in

```
def h():
    global xxx
    x = 99
```

the resulting byte code is indistinguishable from `g`:

```
>>> dis.dis(h)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (99)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: can you check this one out, and maybe explain why nonlocal behaves differently?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287522/nonlocal-statement-got-checked-without-running-the-function-in-python/51287668?noredirect=1#comment89553896_51287668

Comment: `nonlocal` doesn't fall back to the global scope; it only looks in other scopes *between* the current scope and the global scope. Because `x` did not exist in the scope of `f` (the only scope between `g`'s local scope and the global scope), the lookup for `x` on the right-hand side of `x = x * 99` failed. Note that the use of `nonlocal` also allowed this to be caught by the parser as a `SyntaxError`, rather than a lookup error.

Comment: When `g` is being defined, the scope of `f` has already been established, allowing the parser to recognize if `x` is in scope, even if `f` itself doesn't actually provide an assignment until *after* `def g` is parsed. (I'm assuming it's not strictly a syntax error in the sense of the code not being parseable, but rather a static analysis step taken after the source for `f` is actually fully parsed.)