# `SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'topics_with_log_tag' found` although it's bounded

Tags: django

I'd like to fetch topics with a specified 'log' tag:

Within the nested function `get_topics_with_log_tag`, I set variable `topics_with_log_tag` nonlocal:

```
def log(request):
    """Show all topics and entries with  log tags"""

    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    #select entries with log tag
    def get_topics_with_log_tag(topics):
        nonlocal topics_with_log_tag
        topics_with_log_tag = []
        for topic in topics:
            for entry in topic.entry_set.all():
                if "#log" in entry.tags:
                    topics_with_log_tag.append(topic)

    get_topics_with_log_tag(topics)
```

It throw SyntaxError:

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'topics_with_log_tag' found
```

Actually, I did bind it `topics_with_log_tag = []`

The above code could be rewrite in a redundant way as

```
topics = Topic.objects.all()
#select entries with log tag
def get_topics_with_log_tag(topics):
    # nonlocal topics_with_log_tag
    topics_with_log_tag = []
    for topic in topics:
        for entry in topic.entry_set.all():
            if "#log" in entry.tags:
                topics_with_log_tag.append(topic)
    return topics_with_log_tag

topics_with_log_tag = get_topics_with_log_tag(topics)
```

What's the problem with my usage of `nonlocal`?

I found the error.

Willem Van Onsem introduces database level filter instead of the nested for loop.

The models.py

```
 class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: If you write `nonlocal` it looks for a variable from an outer scope. But there is none. Nevertheless you can do this filtering at the database level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error on nonlocal statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264313/syntax-error-on-nonlocal-statement-in-python)

Comment: Got your idea, could you please post a database solution as an answer. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Tool: can you post the relevant parts of your models (`Topic`, `Entry`, and `Tag`?)?

Comment: I append Topic, Entry and tags, are those sufficient? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## How `nonlocal` works

If you use `nonlocal`, that means that Python will, at the start of the function, look for a variable with the same name from one scope above (and beyond). But here you did not define such one. We can fix it with defining one, one level higher:

```
def log(request):
    """Show all topics and entries with  log tags"""

    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    #select entries with log tag
    topics_with_log_tag = []
    def get_topics_with_log_tag(topics):
        nonlocal topics_with_log_tag
        topics_with_log_tag = []
        for topic in topics:
            for entry in topic.entry_set.all():
                if "#log" in entry.tags:
                    topics_with_log_tag.append(topic)

    get_topics_with_log_tag(topics)
```

You can use `global` in which case you do not need to declare such variable (in that case it is declared at the upper level), but this is actually an anti-pattern as well.

## Efficient database querying in Django ORM

Nevertheless the way you perform the filtering here, will usually be quite inefficient: you here first iterate over all `Topic`s, then for each topic, you do an extra query fetching all `Entry`s, then for each `Entry` you fetch all `Tag`s, and then you look whether one of the tags is `#log`. Now imagine that you have 10 topics, that have 10 entries per topic, and 5 tags per entry. That results in 500+ queries you do at the database level. We can construct a filter like:

```
topics_with_log_tag = Topics.objects.filter(entry__tags__contains='#log').distinct()
```

or more readable (brackets are used to allow multi-line expressions):

```
topics_with_log_tag = (Topics.objects
                             .filter(entry__tags__contains='#log')
                             .distinct())
```

Note that the above will (just like your code did), also contains topics with as `tags` for example `'#logarithm'`. It only checks if it contains a certain substring. In order to prevent that, you will need more advanced filtering, or better tag representation (with an end marker).

For example if every topic ends with a comma (like `'#foo,#bar,'`) then we could query for `'#log,'`.

We can also work with regular expressions and check for a new hash character, or the end of the string.

Comment: great tutorial, I found  the regex filter following your instruction.

Comment: I am wondering for days why you encapsulated the QuerySet with `()`, until I read 'QuerySets are lazy'. You explicitly stated that querysets are tuple rather than list.

Comment: @JawSaw: since that allows a new line when we use a `.` making it more readable. A tuple is *not* `(<expr>)`. 1-element tuples exist, but then you need a comma, like `(1,)`.

Comment: @JawSaw: for the given `ForeignKey` relation, it is `entry_set`, only if you use `OneToOne` relations, etc. the *automatic* reverse-name is `entry`. You can also edit the name manually. But by default if there can be multiple in the reverse, then it is written with `_set` suffix.

Comment: It's amazing, much better than official tutorial's multiple lines. What's (<expr>), google searches not helpful.

Comment: I got it,` ("itself")` return itself but steal multiple lines feature.

Comment: @JawSaw: yes :) semantically the two are the same. But I have the idea the latter is more readable, since one does not has to scroll that much to see what is written. One can also group it more semantically (one task per line, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

```
def log(request):
    """Show all topics and entries with  log tags"""
    topics_with_log_tag=[]
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    #select entries with log tag
    def get_topics_with_log_tag(topics):
        nonlocal topics_with_log_tag
        topics_with_log_tag = []
        for topic in topics:
            for entry in topic.entry_set.all():
                if "#log" in entry.tags:
                    topics_with_log_tag.append(topic)

    get_topics_with_log_tag(topics)
```

you can only nonlocal the local variables not global variables