# How does Python handle inner functions with nonlocal effects on their parameters?

Tags: python, scoping

Consider the following function, which we'd like to not be constant on integers `a`, but which always returns `(1,2)`:

```
def foo(a):
    b = 1
    c = 2
    def bar(b,c):
        b = b + a
        c = c + a
    bar(b,c)
    return (b,c)
```

If I understand correctly, the idiomatic way to implement `bar(b,c)` would be to give it no parameters at all and declare b and c nonlocal inside its definition. I'm curious, however: how do we make an inner function have nonlocal effects on its parameters?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That sounds like a recipe for impenetrable code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local functions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414304/local-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414320/5276734) for Python 2.x:

> Python doesn't allow you to reassign the value of a variable from an
>   outer scope in an inner scope (unless you're using the keyword
>   "global", which doesn't apply in this case).

This will return `(2,3)`:

```
def foo(a):
    b = 1
    c = 2
    def bar(b,c):
        b = b + a
        c = c + a
        return b, c
    b, c = bar(b,c)
    return (b,c)

print(foo(1))
```

Comment: You are quoting a *Python 2 answer*. Python 3 has the `nonlocal` keyword for this, invalidating the quote.

Comment: Right, but the quote has still no bearing whatsoever on *this question*.

Answer (score 2):

Make `b` and `c` [function attributes.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/)

```
def foo(a):
    foo.b = 1
    foo.c = 2
    def bar():
        foo.b = foo.b + a
        foo.c = foo.c + a
    bar()
    return (foo.b,foo.c)
```

Notice you no longer pass b or c into the function bar.

Comment: You may as well mark them `nonlocal`, for all the difference this makes.

Comment: Also, if `bar` is shared outside of `foo`, then those attributes act like globals, any code can manipulate them and alter the outcome. They are **not** the same thing as parameters or `nonlocal` closures.

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters are **always** locals. You could pass in mutable objects however, and apply your operations to the indirectly referenced value:

```
def foo(a):
    b = [1]
    c = [2]
    def bar(b, c):
        b[0] += a
        c[0] += a
    bar(b, c)
    return (b[0], c[0])
```

The changes you make to the mutable object are shared with any other references to those objects, including locals in `foo()`.

However, if you want something to be a closure, just make it a closure. There are no use cases for this that cannot be handled by `nonlocal` values and `return`.