# Is num a bound variable or a free variable?

Tags: python, sicp, bound-variable

```
def function()
    num = 1
    num += 1
    return num
```

Is num a bound variable or a free variable?

P.S. This code is written in python. There's no former code ahead of this.

Comment: Many argue that python does not have variables.  You might consider the *object* instead.  There are two objects in use here, 1 and 2.  `num` is reference to the object, and is scoped within the function.

Comment: You should surely read: [Python internals: Symbol tables, part 1](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1)

Comment: @cdarke One simply cannot sat Python doesn't have variables because it work differently than C when it works almost identical to how variables works in Lisp. Those objects are in fact what the variable `num` resolves to at different stages but not the variable itself.

Comment: @Sylwester:  I said *Many argue* that python does not have variables, I don't argue that, but I can see their point.

Answer (score 1):

From [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) : *If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless declared as nonlocal. If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable. (The variables of the module code block are local and global.) If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable*.

Here `num` is defined in `function` and as such is bound to it.

You can look to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919351/3545273) from SO to have an example of free variable