# Python Why `import` does not work in this case (in `exec`)?

Tags: python

Sorry but the situation a bit complicated that I can't describe it clearly in the title.

So this is the script to be imported later in `exec`:

```py
# script_to_be_imported.py

def f():
    print("Hello World!")
```

And this is my main script:

```py
# main.py

script = """
import script_to_be_imported
def function_to_use_the_imported_script():
    script_to_be_imported.f()

function_to_use_the_imported_script()
"""


def function_invokes_exec():
    exec(script)


function_invokes_exec()
```

I am using `Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`, and it tells me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yueyinqiu\Documents\MyTemporaryFiles\stackoverflow\importInExec\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    function_invokes_exec()
  File "C:\Users\yueyinqiu\Documents\MyTemporaryFiles\stackoverflow\importInExec\main.py", line 13, in function_invokes_exec
    exec(script)
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in function_to_use_the_imported_script
NameError: name 'script_to_be_imported' is not defined
```

But when I make some small changes which I think they are unrelated, it could work correctly.

For example, it works when `exec` is invoked outside the function:

```py
# main.py

script = """
import script_to_be_imported
def function_to_use_the_imported_script():
    script_to_be_imported.f()

function_to_use_the_imported_script()
"""

exec(script)
```

and also works when:

```py
# main.py

script = """
import script_to_be_imported
script_to_be_imported.f()
"""


def function_invokes_exec():
    exec(script)


function_invokes_exec()
```

It even works when a value is passed to `global` although it's just an empty dictionary:

```py
# main.py

script = """
import script_to_be_imported
def function_to_use_the_imported_script():
    script_to_be_imported.f()

function_to_use_the_imported_script()
"""


def function_invokes_exec():
    exec(script, {})


function_invokes_exec()
```

So have I misunderstood something? Or it is a bug of python?

Comment: Additional arguments of `exec(...)` let you specify the local and global namespaces to.be used, separately, as dicts. (This is reldvant for Python 3.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> ...if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the
> "current scope".

The current scope here is the local namespace of the `function_invokes_exec` function.

If you look closely, the error comes from this line `script_to_be_imported.f()` inside `function_to_use_the_imported_script` function.

before `function_to_use_the_imported_script` gets called, what do we have in the local scope of `function_invokes_exec`?

1. `script_to_be_imported`
2. `function_to_use_the_imported_script`

Now when `function_to_use_the_imported_script` gets called and encounters a name, it should either look at *"its"* local namespace or global module(forget about nonlocal namespace for now<sup>[1]</sup>). `script_to_be_imported` is not in its local, is it inside the global namespace? No! So it can't find it. Where is it? It's in `function_invokes_exec`'s local namespace. Does `function_to_use_the_imported_script` have access to that namespace? No.

Beside your mentioned cases, if you import `script_to_be_imported` in the global namespace it would also work:

```py
# main.py
import script_to_be_imported

script = """
def function_to_use_the_imported_script():
    script_to_be_imported.f()

function_to_use_the_imported_script()
"""

def function_invokes_exec():
    exec(script)

function_invokes_exec()
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup>: Actually if a function is defined "inside" another function, [it has access to the enclosing namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12919278/13944524). It's called "nonlocal" namespace. But here since `function_to_use_the_imported_script` hasn't been defined there, I didn't talk about it. Thanks to @Kellybundy for bringing the point up.