# How do I lock these attributes?

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I've only just started coding, so I thought I would try and make something simple, however, I can't select the objects from my `ls`, I know the error is in my `def attrLockT` and was wondering if anyone could help me to fix this issue and understand what I am doing wrong?

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

#Selects the attributes

sat = ['.tx', '.ty', '.tz']
sar = ['.rx', '.ry', '.rz']
sas = ['.sx', '.sy', '.sz']

#Creates the list of currently selected objects

myList = cmds.ls(sl = True)

#Lock the translate attributes of the selected objects

def attrLockT(*args):
    checkAttr=cmds.getAttr (myList[0] + sat)

    if (checkAttr == 0):
        cmds.setAttr(myList[0] + sat, lock = 1)

#Delete window if it is already open
if cmds.window('animationCtrl', exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI('animationCtrl', window=True)

#Setup the window
cmds.window(
    'animationCtrl',
    title = "Animation Controls",
    widthHeight = (300, 500),
    s = False)

form = cmds.formLayout()
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)
cmds.formLayout(
    form, 
    edit=True,
    attachForm=(
        (tabs, 'top', 0),
        (tabs, 'left', 0),
        (tabs, 'bottom', 0),
        (tabs, 'right', 0)))


#Layout for the first tab
child1 = cmds.gridLayout( numberOfRowsColumns=(4, 3) , cwh = (100, 50))
cmds.text(label = "")
cmds.text(label = "Lock", align = "center", h = 20, w = 250)
cmds.text(label = "")
cmds.button(label = "Translate", h = 300, w = 250, c = attrLockT)
cmds.button(label = "Rotate", h = 50, w = 250)
cmds.button(label = "Scale", h = 50, w = 250)
cmds.text(label = "")
cmds.text(label = "Unlock", align = "center", h = 20, w = 250)
cmds.text(label = "")
cmds.button(label = "Translate", h = 50, w = 250)
cmds.button(label = "Rotate", h = 50, w = 250)
cmds.button(label = "Scale", h = 50, w = 250)
cmds.setParent( '..' )

#Layout for the second tab
child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=3)
cmds.button()
cmds.button()
cmds.button()
cmds.setParent( '..' )

cmds.tabLayout(
    tabs,
    edit=True,
    tabLabel=((child1, 'Lock/Unlock'), (child2, 'Keyable/Unkeyable')))

cmds.showWindow('animationCtrl')
```

The error that is thrown is

```
# Error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 16, in attrLockT
# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: oh MEL.. where's your error point in that code and what it actually said

Comment: The problem is that sat is a list while mylist[0] is a string, so you can't add them.  You want to loop through sat and and the strings to myList[0] one at a time, locking each attribute in turn

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

`myList[0] + sat`

Is `myList[0]` type of `list` ? Because the `sat` variable is certainly `list`.

If `myList` is just a list of `string` then `myList[0]` will be just one element of type `string` and it will produce an error.

Simplify your program, just leave only locking routine and window with button to see what will happen, be sure that the right name of an object + attribute is passed to `getAttr` - just `string` like `'obj.attrib'`.

**Some python specific clues for your function**

If you need to sum two lists:

```
[ objName + attName for objName, attName in zip(myList, sat) ]
```

that will result, for example, in `['obj1.tx', 'obj2.ty', 'obj3.tz']`

If you need apply a list of attributes to an object:

```py
[ myList[0] + a for a in sat ]
```

that will result in `['obj1.tx', 'obj1.ty', 'obj1.tz']`

If you need apply the same list of attributes to all objects:

```py
[ objName + attName for objName in myList for attName in sat ]
```

will result in `['obj1.tx', 'obj1.ty', 'obj1.tz', 'obj2.tx', ..., 'obj3.tz']`

Then you can call your locking function over that result list:

```py
def locker(a):
    checkAttr = cmds.getAttr(a)
    if (checkAttr == 0):
        cmds.setAttr(a, lock = 1)
```

and finally it should look:

```py
def attrLockT(*args):
    atrlist = [ ..... ]
    for a in atrlist:
        locker(a)
```

Comment: No it doesn't, I changed it to sat[0] (through to 2) and it doesn't give an error any more, however, it doesn't do the function I want it to do, any ideas how to fix this?
What I want to do is create a button that locks an attribute in maya for selected objects

Comment: I tried what you suggested using the 
    [ objName + attName for objName in myList for attName in sat ]
However, this only locks the Translate Y of the first object in the list, so I'm a little more confused :/ Thank you for all of your help though

Comment: @luke try oversee what happens, i.e place `print a` in `def loocker(a)` body to see what the attributes come for locking, also put `print checkAttr` after `cmds.getAtrr(a)` to see what it will return

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

first, you want to loop through the individual attributes and concatenate them with object names:

```
def lockTranslate(*args):
    for obj in mylist:
        for attr in ['.tx', '.ty', '.tz']: 
            cmds.setAttr(obj + "." + attr, l=True)
```

second, and maybe more important, you will likely have problems the scope of your functions. In the form you have it typed in, variables like myList and sat, etc are accessible to the function through [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python) - it will work if you execute all of this in the listener, but if you break the closure (for example, if this goes into a function that gets called by another function) things wont work -- myList will be stuck pointing at whatever was selected when the function was *defined*.

In this particular case you probably want to just operate on selection instead of inheriting myList:

```
def lockTranslate(*args):
    for obj in cmds.ls(sl=True, type = 'transform'):
        for attr in ['.tx', '.ty', '.tz']: 
            cmds.setAttr(obj + "." + attr, l=True)
```