# Why isn't the instances variable lost after executing the function?

Tags: python, variables, singleton

Normally, I would expect a function variable to be lost after execution of that function. In the below case where I wrote a Singleton following some tutorials, it works, though. One could argue that `instances`should be empty again everytime the `singleton` function is called.

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]
    return get_instance

@singleton
class cls(object):
    pass
```

My assumption is that indeed `instances` would be lost if it weren't the case that a dynamic function `get_instance`is returned in which a reference to the variable is stored so that it is still available. This leads to the fact that `instances` continues existing.

Is that interpretation correct? Is it also correct that for every `get_instance` call there is a separate "instance" of `instances`? They cannot be the same as for every `singleton` call there is a fresh `instances = {}`.

Comment: I'm gonna just share the link to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
>>> @singleton
>>> class cls(object):
...    pass
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
>>> class cls(object):
...    pass
>>> cls = singleton( cls )
```

`singleton` is run only once per class you decorate it with (not per instantiation). The function it *returns*, which is a different instance of `get_instance` for every time `singleton` is called, is run once per instantiation. Thus only one `instances` object is created even when you attempt to instantiate many `cls` objects.

Note what sort of callable `cls` actually is after the above:

```
>>> cls
<function get_instance at 0x0000000002352B38>
```

The `instances` objects are not reclaimed until it they are no longer reachable because Python uses [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). It is considered reachable as long as the function `get_instance`, which [closes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) over it, is reachable.

Comment: Okay, my assumption probably wasn't explained 100% clearly. Per "singletoned" class there is one `instances` *each*. That's what I thought. Yes, there is only one `instances` per class, no matter how often you instantiate it. Would you agree with me?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, that's right. That object is still reachable through a closure, so it's not being reclaimed.