# Need for nested functions in python

Tags: python

I am familar in c/c++ amd new to python and I am wondering what is the need for nested functions in python. Can anyone give a live example where we use nested functions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use helper functions (and you don't want to supply arguments), especially with threads:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import thread

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    progress_var = tk.StringVar(root)
    progress_var.set('')
    progress = tk.Label(root, textvariable = progress_var)
    progress.pack()
    def thread_helper(): # this can access the local variables in main()
        total = 10000000
        for i in xrange(1, total + 1):
             progress_var.set('Progress: {}%'.format(100 * float(i)/total))
    thread.start_new_thread(thread_helper, ())
    root.mainloop()
```

What this essentially does is show the progress of the `for` loop in a window. After the `root.mainloop()`, no processes will run, so I need to use a thread to actually initiate the `for` loop, and update the progress display.

The thread requires a function to be called, and it is much easier to just define a helper function (which is nested and only used once) rather than create a new function and pass it various arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is too broad, and is therefore likely to be closed, but two examples are [Decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) and [Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python).