# Tkinter - how to open recent files?

Tags: python, tkinter, submenu

I'm trying to write a function to open a recent file when it's selected from a submenu, but when I loop through the recent files the last file is the only one that is recognized.

Here's a sample bit of code to illustrate the issue:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        menubar = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        recentMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=0)

        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label="Open Recent", menu=recentMenu)
        for name in ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'):
            recentMenu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda: self.load_file(name))

        root.configure(menu=menubar)
        root.geometry("200x200")

    def load_file(self, f):
        print f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    App(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I click on file2.txt for example, the program outputs file3.txt instead. I'm sure I'm missing something trivial, but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: I guess you also see `file3.txt`, when clicking on `file1.txt`?

Comment: @spiehr yep, it seems to always select the last item that's being iterated over in the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following works:

...

```
    for name in ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'):
        recentMenu.add_command(label=name, command=self.load_file(name))
```

...

```
def load_file(self, f):
    def fun():
        print f
    return fun
```

In your version, at the moment, when you call the callback function, `name` refers to the instance `file3.txt`. In my version, the instances `file1.txt`, `file2,txt`, and so on, are captured inside closures (not strictly a closure, but very similar).

See [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python) in SO.