# Behaviour I don't understand in Python mixings comprehension lists and lambda-functions

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I don't understand the behaviour of a piece of code, involving a comprehension list over lambda functions that call a method in different objects. It happened in a large program, so for this question I made a nonsensical toy-case to show my point:

```
class Evaluator(object):
    def __init__(self, lft, rgt):
        self.lft = lft
        self.rgt = rgt

    def eval(self, x):
        return self.lft + x * (self.rgt - self.lft)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ev1 = Evaluator(2, 3)
    ev2 = Evaluator(4, 5)
    ev3 = Evaluator(6, 7)
    funcs = [lambda x:ev.eval(x+0.1) for ev in (ev1, ev2, ev3)]
    print([f(0.5) for f in funcs])
```

The output I get is `[6.6, 6.6, 6.6]`, which means that it is the method in `ev3` the one that is being evaluated all the time. Instead of `[2.6, 4.6, 6.6]`, as I would have expected. But what really surprises me is that if I get rid of the lambda-function, the behaviour is fine:

```
class Evaluator(object):
    def __init__(self, lft, rgt):
        self.lft = lft
        self.rgt = rgt

    def eval(self, x):
        return self.lft + x * (self.rgt - self.lft)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ev1 = Evaluator(2, 3)
    ev2 = Evaluator(4, 5)
    ev3 = Evaluator(6, 7)
    funcs = [ev.eval for ev in (ev1, ev2, ev3)]
    print([f(0.5) for f in funcs])
```

returns `[2.5, 4.5, 6.5]`. Can anyone explain what is going on here? And how should I code this in a Pythoninstic way?

Comment: The `ev` in the lambda is bound to the variable, not the value. It changes when `ev` changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are only ever evaluating ev *at the time you call the function*. Thus, it's using whatever value `ev` has only when you start the print statement. Of course, by that time `ev` has the value of the last function in the list.

This is no different than if you had done this:

```
funcs = [lambda x: ev.eval(x+0.1),
         lambda x: ev.eval(x+0.1),
         lambda x: ev.eval(x+0.1)]
```

Notice how they all use `ev`, and they will all use the *same* `ev` at the time you run the functions.

To do what you want, you need to bind `ev` to its current value in the list comprehension at the time you *define* the comprehension, which you can do by passing in the value through the lambda arguments:

```
funcs = [lambda x, ev=ev: ev.eval(x+0.1) for ev in (ev1, ev2, ev3)]
```

However, I strongly suggest you do *not* do this. As you have just experienced, such code is very hard to understand and debug. You win no points for cramming as much functionality into a single line as possible.

The technical term for this is a closure. For more information, check out this question on stackoverflow:
[Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020419/7432)

Comment: I see, I had never found this issue before. Time to read about closures again. Thank you both Brian and @pavelannosov for your explanation and (identical) solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python)

These lambdas are closures that use the name `ev` from the enclosing scope. When the lambdas are executed, `ev` is bound to `ev3`.

Observe:

```
a = 1

def x():
    print a

a = 2

x()   # prints 2
```

Here `ev` is evaluated at the lambda's creation:

```
funcs = [lambda x, e=ev: e.eval(x + 0.1) for ev in (ev1, ev2, ev3)]
print([f(0.5) for f in funcs])
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because of the way lambdas are evaluated. All three lambdas are this:

```
ev.eval(x+0.1)
```

But after the comprehension, the value of `ev` is `ev3`, and so all three lambdas are the same.

You can observe this by deleting `ev` before evaluating the functions. You will get an attribute error.