# Python: Button command + '&'

Tags: python, function, button, turtle-graphics

I got an error at this code:
The error is in my function settings() in the Button() command. but I don't got any plan how to fix it, sorry. I can't put the 3 commands in an external function, cause it wouldn't get the variables...

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
reset()
hastrail = 1
def moveup():
    setheading(90)
    forward(5)
def movedown():
    setheading(270)
    forward(5)
def moveright():
    setheading(0)
    forward(5)
def moveleft():
    setheading(180)
    forward(5)
def turnleft():
    left(18)
def turnright():
    right(18)
def forw():
    forward(5)
def backw():
    backward(5)
def trailrem():
    global hastrail
    if hastrail == 1:
        penup()
        hastrail = 0
    else:
        pendown()
        hastrail = 1
def settings():
    color(str(colorchooser.askcolor(title = "Change a line color")[1]),str(colorchooser.askcolor(title = "Change a fill color")[1]))
    tk = Tk ()
    tk.resizable(0,0)
    tk.title("Shape, Shapesize, Pensize")
    tk.geometry("400x90")
    listbox = Listbox(tk)
    listbox.place(x=0,y=0,width=200,height=90)
    listbox.insert(1,"arrow")
    listbox.insert(2,"turtle")
    listbox.insert(3,"circle")
    listbox.insert(4,"square")
    listbox.insert(5,"triangle")
    shsi = Scale(tk,width = 10,orient = HORIZONTAL)
    shsi.place(x=200,y=0,width=200,height=30)
    trsi = Scale(tk,width = 10, orient = HORIZONTAL)
    trsi.place(x=200,y=30,width=200,height=30)
    Button(tk,text="Save",command = lambda:shape(str(listbox.get(ACTIVE)))&shapesize(int(shsi.get()))&pensize(int(trsi.get()))).place(x=200,y=60,width=200,height=30)

onkeypress(moveup,"Up")
onkeypress(movedown,"Down")
onkeypress(moveright,"Right")
onkeypress(moveleft,"Left")
onkeypress(turnleft,"a")
onkeypress(turnright,"d")
onkeypress(forw,"w")
onkeypress(backw,"s")
onkeypress(trailrem,"t")
onkeypress(settings,"c")
listen()
mainloop()
```

Pls tell me what I've done wrong // fix it pls.

Comment: What's the specific problem? Do you get an error message, or a stack trace? What do you expect to happen? What's happening instead?

Comment: Also, your formatting is *horrendous*. This code is impossible to read. Have a look at [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide.

Comment: I got an error message. I wanted to change the turtles Shape, Shapesize and Pensize in one Button command. The pensize doesn't change, and an error message comes up: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'"

Comment: _"I can't put the 3 commands in an external function  cause it wouldn't get the variables"_ [Python has closure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4020443/2363712), you know.

Comment: I got the error just in this line. Pls look for it: "Button(tk,text="Save",command = lambda:shape(str(listbox.get(ACTIVE)))&shapesize(int(shsi.get()))&pensize(int(trsi.get()))).place(x=200,y=60,width=200,height=30)"

Comment: Try looking up what the [`&` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-17) actually does. You probably want to do something else.

Comment: Just wanna get a variable of one function into another function...

Comment: Ok. lets try a different symbol..

Comment: Doesn't work with '^'

Comment: @ProgrammingDonkey, did you just randomly pick another operator from the bitwise section of the documentation? The reason I pointed you to the docs was so that you'd *read them*. Bitwise operators are not what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to string together multiple expressions using the `&` operator, it isn't likely to work well, unless all of your function calls return integers, which isn't the case here. I don't recommend it, but you can put each command as a separate element of a collection such as a list or tuple:

```
Button(tk,text="Save",command = lambda:[
    shape(str(listbox.get(ACTIVE))),
    shapesize(int(shsi.get())),
    pensize(int(trsi.get()))
]).place(x=200,y=60,width=200,height=30)
```

> I can't put the 3 commands in an external function, cause it wouldn't get the variables

Ordinarily, this is true. But if you define the second function *inside* the first, all of its variables will still be visible.

```
def settings():
    def save_button_clicked():
        shape(str(listbox.get(ACTIVE)))
        shapesize(int(shsi.get()))
        pensize(int(trsi.get()))
    #rest of `settings` code goes here...
    Button(tk,text="Save",command = save_button_clicked).place(x=200,y=60,width=200,height=30)
```