# understand closure in python

Tags: python, closures

i try to understand closure by the following codes

main

```
class foo(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.a=10
      def test(self):
          def re():
              print self.a
          return re        


f1=foo()
k1=f1.test()
k1()#               output 10
f1.a=20#            line A
k1()#               output 20
```

appends case1 or case2

case1:

```
del f1#             line B
k1()#               line C output 20
```

case2:

```
del f1.a
k1()#               line D .error
```

from line A, it seems k1() output depends on f1.a. if i deleted f1, f1.a should be removed. why does lineC output 20? .   if k1() does not depend on f1.a , why does  lineD output error? please help to explain . thanks

Comment: `del f1` affects the current scope, not the object `f1` directly. `del f1.a` changes `f1`, which `re()` refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not totally accurate to say "`k1` depends on `f1.a`".  `k1` makes use of the expression `self.a`, and `self.a` is not an atomic unit, but is made of a bare name (self) and an attribute (a).  Either one of these can fail independently.  In the second case, it is only the attribute lookup that fails (i.e., the object does not have an attribute `a`).

By doing `del f1`, you did not delete the object.  You only deleted the *name* `f1`.  If there are other references to that object, the object will still exist.  And there is another reference, namely in the closure of `k1`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135926/why-is-the-variable-still-available-after-the-function-is-executed/) for more explanation, but basically when you call `f1.test()`, the value of `self` for that call is "saved" within the returned function (what you called `k1`), because `self` is a local variable of the enclosing function `test`.  Thus `k1` still has access to the object formerly known as `f1`, and the call succeeds.

In your second case, you deleted the attribute `a` from the object known as `f1`.  `re` does not save a reference to that attribute, because closures only save local variables of the enclosing function.  When you call `re`, it tries to look up `self.a`, and this fails because, although the object exists, the attribute isn't there.

One thing that may be helpful in understanding the difference: notice that `re` does not make use of the *name* `f1`.  It refers to the name `self`.  In your setup, this winds up being the same object as `f1`, but the object has two different names pointing at it.  In contrast, `re` *does* make use of the attribute name `a`, and it is that usage which fails when it's called in your Case 2.

If `re` *did* use the name `f1`, it would also fail if that name were deleted.  If you change `re` to do `print f1.a` instead of `print self.a`, then it will be looking for a global variable with the name `f1`, and will fail if that variable does not exist.  In this case, it never gets to try looking for an attribute `a`, since the object doesn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

*if i deleted f1, f1.a should be removed*

That's not correct. if you `del f1`, it decreases reference counter of `f1` object and removes it from local **dict** so it becomes inaccessible. When ref. counter reaches 0, Python GC returns occupied memory to the OS.

When you create closures that access outer context, Python implicitly creates references to that context in local closure scope. Add `print(locals())`  before `print self.a` to see that foo object is referenced in k1.

So when you delete `f1` in case 1 with existing `k1`, `f1` disappears from module's context, but the object still exists with a single reference in `k1`. So it's ok to call `k1()` and get 20.

When you `del f1.a` in case 2, it deletes `a` from the context of `f1` object. There's only one object f1 so `a` becomes inaccessible neither from `f1.a` nor from `k1`.