# Understanding Function Closures

Tags: python

I'm struggling to understand Function closures properly. For example in the code below I am unclear as to how the function knows that in the statement `times3(2)` that `x=2`? Also, after reading documentations I still can't fully understand the purpose of closures.

```
def make_multiplier_of(n):
    def multiplier(x):
        return x * n
    return multiplier

times3 = make_multiplier_of(3)
times3(2) #How does the function know that x=2 here?
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `times3` is *actually `multiplier`*, the argument `2` is passed to the parameter `x` of that function. It is `n` that's affected by the closure, not `x`.

Comment: I don't get what you don't get... You are calling the function so obviously it knows about its own arguments. It knows about `n` because that's what a closure do, but `x` is just a plain argument.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python. it will help.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling `make_multiplier_of(3)`, the function is returning `multiplier` such that

```
def multiplier(x):
    return x*3
```

So `times3 = make_multipiler(3)` is assigning this particular `multiplier` function to `times3`. The same way that when you are doing `myLength=len`, `myLength` is the `len` function and you can call `myLength("foo")`

`times3` is thus this `multiplier` function. So when you `times3(2)`, you are doing (this particular) `multiplier(2)`