# Don't understand how this nested function works

Tags: python

```
def raise_val(n):
    def inner(x):
        raised = x**n
        return raised
    return inner

square = raise_val(2)
print(square(2))# gives 4 as output
```

I don't understand how this nested function works...also why does `square(2)` output 4?
Isn't `square` just a variable?

Comment: What do you mean "provide" it? And *"I don't understand"* isn't actually a question.

Comment: you might want to look in to first class objects and how they work in python

Comment: gives 4 as output.

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question. It's not clear why that was unexpected or what you're trying to ask. Square is just a variable, yes, but its value is a function.

Comment: `type(square)` would be enlightening.

Comment: ivan_pozdeev: plz elaborate...I am new to programming...the link is hard for me to understand...

Comment: what is the value of x in this operation? we only feed the value of n inside...how can n be equal to 2...I don't understand how type(square) is a function...shouldn't it be an integer?

Comment: If you are really new. I'd suggest coming back to this after you have some more of the basics under your belt. It's not super advanced in the scheme of things, but sometimes when there are just too many new concepts involved it can be tough going to figure out.

Comment: Why would square be an integer? raise_val returns inner, which isn't an integer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423550/understanding-function-closures?noredirect=1&lq=1.  This link solved my problem...thanx all

Answer (score 2):

This is called higher-order functions in functional programming languages. Python also uses this paradigm.

A higher-order function is a function that either/both accepts a function as an argument and/or returns a function as a result. Your function `raise_val` is a higher order function in the sense that it is returning back a function. Your variable `square` has a function (the `inner`).

When you call `raise_val(2)` what you do is that you return a partial function that needs to be evaluated. Then with `square(2)` you are passing `2` to the `inner` partial function that uses the `2` for `n` when you initially called `raise_val(2)`.

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 1):

In python, functions are values, too.

So, every time that you call `raise_val`, you are generating a new "inner" function which has a different constant for the `n` variable.

You are assigning this new function to the variable `square`, and then calling this new function.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `square = raise_val(2)`, you provide the `n=2` parameter to `inner` and `raise_val` returns you the inner function and stores it in the`square` variable.

```
def raise_val(n):
    def inner(x):
        raised = x**n
        return raised
    return inner # This returns a function, not a number!
```

This is why you can **call** square later by writing `square(2)`. Here you provided the `x=2` argument.

```
print(square(2))# gives 4 as output
```

What you did is equivalent to printing `raise_val(n=2)(x=2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Line by line explanation:

- `def raise_val(n):` begin defenition of a function, `raise_val`, which accepts `n` as a parameter.

  - `def inner(x):` begin defenition of a function *within `raise_val`*, called `inner`, which accepts `x` as a parameter

    - `raised = x**n` set variable `raised` as `x`(the argument given to `inner`) to the power of `n`(the argument given to `raise_val`)
    - `return raised` return `raised` as the return value of `inner`
  - `return inner` return *the function `inner`* as the return value of `raise_val`
- `square = raise_val(2)` set a new variable `square` as the output of the function `raise_val` when called with an argument `2`, which will be a function that takes a number `x` and return it squared
- `print(square(2))` call the variable `square` with paramter `2`, thus returning 2 to the power 2, or 4, which it then prints