# Dynamically update attributes of an object that depend on the state of other attributes of same object

Tags: python

Say I have an class that looks like this:

```
class Test(object):
   def __init__(self, a, b):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.c = self.a + self.b
```

I would like the value of `self.c` to change whenever the value of attributes `self.a` or `self.b` changes for the same instance.

e.g.

```
test1 = Test(2,4)
print test1.c # prints 6

test1.a = 3
print test1.c # prints = 6
```

I know why it would still print 6, but is there a mechanism I could use to fire an update to `self.c` when `self.a` has changed. Or the only option I have is to have a method that returns me the value of `self.c` based on the current state of `self.a` and `self.b`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, there is! It's called properties.

### Read Only Properties

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

With the above code, `c` is now a read-only property of the `Test` class.

### Mutable Properties

You can also give a property a *setter*, which would make it read/write and allow you to set its value directly. It would look like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, c = SomeDefaultValue):
        self._c = SomeDefaultValue
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c
    @c.setter
    def c(self,value):
        self._c = value
```

However, in this case, it would not make sense to have a setter for `self.c`, since its value depends on `self.a` and `self.b`.

### What does @property mean?

The `@property` bit is an example of something called a *decorator*. A decorator actually *wraps* the function (or class) it decorates into another function (the decorator function). After a function has been decorated, when it is called it is actually the decorator that is called with the function (and its arguments) as an argument. Usually (but not always!) the decorated function does something interesting, and then calls the original (decorated) function like it would normally. For example:

```
def my_decorator(thedecoratedfunction):
    def wrapped(*allofthearguments):
        print("This function has been decorated!") #something interesting
        thedecoratedfunction(*allofthearguments)   #calls the function as normal
    return wrapped

@my_decorator
def myfunction(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def myfunction(arg1, arg2):
    pass
myfunction = my_decorator(myfunction)
```

So this means in the class example above, instead of using the decorator you could also do this:

```
def c(self):
    return self.a + self.b
c = property(c)
```

They are exactly the same thing. The `@property` is just syntactic sugar to replace calls for `myobject.c` with the property getter and setter (deleters are also an option).

### Wait - How does that work?

You might be wondering why simply doing this *once*:

```
myfunction = my_decorator(myfunction)
```

...results in such a drastic change! So that, from now on, when calling:

```
myfunction(arg1, arg2)
```

...you are actually calling `my_decorator(myfunction)`, with `arg1, arg2` sent to the interior `wrapped` function inside of `my_decorator`. And not only that, but all of this happens *even though you didn't even mention `my_decorator` or `wrapped` in your function call at all!*

All of this works by virtue of something called a *closure*. When the function is passed into the decorator in this way (e.g., `property(c)`), the function's name is re-bound to the wrapped version of the function instead of the original function, and the original function's arguments are always passed to `wrapped` instead of the original function. This is simply the way that closures work, and there's nothing magical about it. [Here is some more information about closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/closures-in-python).

### Descriptors

So to summarize so far: `@property` is just a way of wrapping the class method inside of the `property()` function so the wrapped class method is called instead of the original, unwrapped class method. ***But what is the property function?*** What does it do?

The property function adds something called a *descriptor* to the class. Put simply, a descriptor is an object class that can have separate get, set, and delete methods. When you do this:

```
@property
def c(self):
    return self._c
```

...you are adding a descriptor to the `Test` class called `c`, and defining the *get* method (actually, `__get__()`) of the `c` descriptor as equal to the `c(self)` method.

When you do this:

```
@c.setter
def c(self,value):
    self._c
```

...you are defining the *set* method (actually, `__set__()`) of the `c` descriptor as equal to the `c(self,value)` method.

### Summary

An amazing amount of stuff is accomplished by simply adding `@property` to your `def c(self)` method! In practice, you probably don't need to understand all of this right away to begin using it. However, I recommend keeping in mind that when you use `@property`, you are using decorators, closures, and descriptors, and if you are at all serious about learning Python it would be well worth your time to investigate each of these topics on their own.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is to make `c` a read-only [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

Now every time you access `test_instance.c`, it calls the property getter and calculates the appropriate value from the other attributes. In use:

```
>>> t = Test(2, 4)
>>> t.c
6
>>> t.a = 3
>>> t.c
7
```

Note that this means that you cannot set `c` directly:

```
>>> t.c = 6

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    t.c = 6
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```