# Return function with function

Tags: python, function, return

I would like to do something like the following:

```
def getFunction(params):
   f= lambda x:
       do stuff with params and x
   return f
```

I get invalid syntax on this. What is the Pythonic/correct way to do it?

This way I can call `f(x)` without having to call `f(x,params)` which is a little more messy IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `lambda` expression is a very limited way of creating a function, you can't have multiple lines/expressions (per [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), *"They are syntactically restricted to a single expression"*). However, you can nest standard function `def`initions:

```
def getFunction(params):
   def to_return(x):
       # do stuff with params and x
   return to_return
```

Functions are first-class objects in Python, so once defined you can pass `to_return` around exactly as you can with a function created using `lambda`, and either way they get access to the "closure" variables (see e.g. [Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020419/3001761)).

Comment: The key point is a `def`'d function is just a first-class value itself, like the result of the lambda, with the same "closure" access.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like what you're actually trying to do is [partial function application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), for which [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) provides a solution. For example, if you have a function `multiply()`:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b
```

... then you can create a `double()` function<sup>1</sup> with one of the arguments pre-filled like this:

```
from functools import partial

double = partial(multiply, 2)
```

... which works as expected:

```
>>> double(7)
14
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically a `partial` object, not a function, but it behaves in the same way.

Comment: Cool. Can you comment on when this library would have use over a solution like johnrsharpe posted above?

Comment: @user3391229 If you want a partial function (as above), use `partial()` - it's less verbose and you're less likely to make a mistake. If you need something more complex, use a closure as in Jon Sharpe's answer. This is an instance of a general rule of thumb in Python - if the included batteries solve your problem, use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a multiline lambda expression in Python, but you can return a lambda or a full function:

```
def get_function1(x):
    f = lambda y: x + y
    return f

def get_function2(x):
    def f(y):
        return x + y
    return f
```