# Closures in Python - variable assignment

Tags: python, scope, closures

When I come across closure in python, from the below code, I don't understand how the values for the arguments assigned for x and y when calling the function. In Point 1, we passing argument value 5 for x. It is then assigned to x in the function. In Point 2, we passing 7 to inc5, My doubt arises here, again the value 7 should assign to x, but instead how come it is assigning to y.

```
def makeInc(x):
    def inc(y):
        return y + x
    return inc

inc5 = makeInc(5) #Point 1
inc5(7) #Point 2
```

Comment: inc5 is a variable, obviously (at Point 1 of course)

Comment: @VIJEE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand why you think 7 should be assigned to x. The outer function `makeInc` returns the *inner* function `inc`, and it's that which you assign to `inc5`. So inc5 accepts the argument `y`, and that's what is bound to the value 7.

Answer (score 1):

At `Point 1` you are passing a varialbe `inc5` the returning result of a `makeInc` function, which will be another function `inc` with a local variable `x` set to 5. Then you call for this new function and pass a 7 as its one and only parameter `y`.