# Pass by value confusion in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, pass-by-value, sicp, shallow-copy

Consider the following procedure taken from [SICP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sicp/info):

```
 (define (make-withdraw balance)
   (lambda (amount)
     (if (>= balance amount)
         (begin (set! balance 
                      (- balance amount))
                balance)
         "Insufficient funds")))
```

Suppose I say:

```
 (define x (make-withdraw 100))
```

`make-withdraw` returns a procedure (`(lambda (amount) ... )`) inside a new environment called `e2` (enclosing the binding for the variable `balance`), and binds that procedure to `x` in the global frame.

Now, say I call:

```
 (f x)
```

where

```
 (define (f y) (y 25))
```

**1**. I've heard that Scheme is pass-by-value. Does this mean that when `f` creates a new environment `e3`, it binds a copy of the value of `x` on `y`?

**2**. That is, the value that `y` (now) holds (after the body of `f` is entered) is a copy of the `lambda` held by `x`?

**3**. So we now have two variables, `x` in global and `y` in `e3`, each containing a procedure that references things inside `e2`?

**4**. If I am correct, are the procedures held by `x` and `y` acting like pointers to `e2`?

Comment: `new-withdraw` is a function with one parameter, but you are calling it without parameters. This should give an error.

Comment: @Renzo, edited. Thanks

Comment: `x` is then bound to the value `0`, returned by the call `(new-withdraw 100)`.

Comment: @Renzo I changed the procedure to make-withdraw and it now returns a lambda.

Answer (score 4):

I find the best way to think about this is to think in terms of *bindings*, rather than environments or frames, which are simply containers for bindings.

### Bindings

A binding is an association between a *name* and a *value*.  The name is often called a 'variable' and the value is, well, the value of the variable.  The value of a binding can be any object that the language can talk about at all.  Bindings, however, are behind-the-scenes things (sometimes this is called 'not being first-class objects'): they're not things that can be represented in the language but rather things that you can use as part of the model of how the language works.  So *the value of a binding can't be a binding*, because bindings are not first-class: the language can't talk about bindings.

There are some rules about bindings:

- there are forms which create them, of which the most important two are `lambda` and `define`;
- bindings are not first-class -- the language can not represent bindings as values;
- bindings are, or may be,  *mutable* -- you can change the value of a binding once it exists -- and the form that does this is `set!`;
- there is no operator which destroys a binding;
- bindings have *lexical scope* -- the bindings available to a bit of code are the ones you can see by looking at it, not ones you have to guess by running the code and which may depend on the dynamic state of the system;
- only one binding for a given name is ever accessible from a given bit of code -- if more than one is lexically visible then the innermost one shadows any outer ones;
- bindings have *indefinite extent* -- if a binding is ever available to a bit of code, it is always available to it.

Obviously these rules need to be elaborated significantly (especially with regards to global bindings & forward-referenced bindings) and mare formal, but these are enough to understand what happens.  In particular I don't really think you need to spend a lot of time worrying about environments: the environment of a bit of code is just the set of bindings accessible to it, so rather than worry about the environment just worry about the bindings.

### Call by value

So, what 'call by value' means is that when you call a procedure with an argument which is a variable (a binding) what is passed to it is the *value* of the variable binding, not the binding itself.  The procedure then creates a *new* binding with the same value.  Two things follow from that:

- the original binding can not be altered by the procedure -- this follows because the procedure only has the value of it, not the binding itself, and bindings are not first-class so you can't cheat by passing the binding itself as the value;
- if the value is itself a mutable object (arrays & conses are example of objects which usually are mutable, numbers are examples of objects which are not) then the procedure can mutate that object.

### Examples of the rules about bindings

So, here are some examples of these rules.

```
(define (silly x)
  (set! x (+ x 1))
  x)

(define (call-something fn val)
  (fn val)
  val))

> (call-something silly 10)
10
```

So, here we are creating two top-level bindings, for `silly` and `call-something`, both of which have values which are procedures.  The value of `silly` is a procedure which, when called:

1. creates a new binding whose name is `x` and whose value is the argument to `silly`;
2. mutates this binding so its value is incremented by one;
3. returns the value of this binding, which is one more than the value it was called with.

The value of `call-something` is a procedure which, when called:

1. creates two bindings, one named `fn` and one named `val`;
2. calls the value of the `fn` binding with the value of the `val` binding;
3. returns the value of the `val` binding.

Note that *whatever* the call to `fn` does, it can not mutate the binding of `val`, because it has no access to it.  So what you can *know*, by looking at the definition of `call-something` is that, if it returns at all (it may not return if the call to `fn` does not return), it will return the value of its second argument.  This guarantee is what 'call by value' means: a language (such as Fortran) which supports other call mechanisms can't always promise this.

```
(define (outer x)
  (define (inner x)
    (+ x 1))
  (inner (+ x 1)))
```

Here there are four bindings: `outer` is a top-level binding whose value is a procedure which, when it is called, creates a binding for `x` whose value is its argument.  It then creates another binding called `inner` whose value is another procedure, which, when it is called, creates a *new* binding for `x` to *its* argument, and then returns the value of that binding plus one.  `outer` then calls this inner procedure with the value of its binding for `x`.

The important thing here is that, in `inner`, there are two bindings for `x` which are potentially lexically visible, but the closest one -- the one established by `inner` -- wins, because only one binding for a given name can ever be accessible at one time.

Here is the previous code (this would not be equivalent if `inner` was recursive) expressed with explicit `lambda`s:

```
(define outer
  (λ (x)
    ((λ (inner)
       (inner (+ x 1)))
     (λ (x)
       (+ x 1)))))
```

And finally an example of mutating bindings:

```
(define (make-counter val)
  (λ ()
    (let ((current val))
      (set! val (+ val 1))
      current)))

> (define counter (make-counter 0))
> (counter)
0
> (counter)
1
> (counter)
2
```

So, here, `make-counter` (is the name of a binding whose value is a procedure which, when called,) establishes a new binding for `val` and then returns a procedure it has created.  This procedure makes a new binding  called `current` which catches the current value of `val`, *mutates* the binding for `val` to add one to it, and returns the value of `current`.  This code exercises the 'if you can ever see a binding, you can always see it' rule: the binding for `val` created by the call to `make-counter` is visible to the procedure it returns for as long as that procedure exists (and that procedure exists at least as long as there is a binding for it), and it also mutates a binding with `set!`.

### Why not environments?

[SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html), in [chapter 3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-19.html#%_chap_3), introduces the 'environment model', where at any point there is an environment, consisting of a sequence of frames, each frame containing bindings.  Obviously this is a fine model, but it introduces three kinds of thing -- the enviromnent, the frames in the environment and the bindings in the frame -- two of which are utterly intangible.  At least for a binding you can get hold of it in some way: you can see it being created in the code and you can see references to it.  So I prefer not to think in terms of these two extra sorts of thing which you can never get any kind of handle on.

However this is a choice which makes no difference in practice: thinking purely in terms of bindings helps me, thinking in terms of environments, frames & bindings may well help other people more.

### Shorthands

In what follows I am going to use a shorthand for talking about bindings, especially top-level ones:

- '`x` is a procedure which ...' means '`x` is the name of a binding whose value is a procedure which, when called, ...';
- '`y` is ...' means '`y` is the name of a binding the value of which is ...';
- '`x` is called with `y`' means 'the value of the binding named by `x` is called with the value of the binding named by `y`';
- '... binds `x` to ...' means '... creates a binding whose name is `x` and whose value is ...';
- '`x`' means 'the value of `x`';
- and so on.

Describing bindings like this is common, as the fully-explicit way is just painful: I've tried (but probably failed in places) to be fully explicit above.

### The answer

And finally, after this long preamble, here's the answer to the question you asked.

```
(define (make-withdraw balance)
  (λ (amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
        (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
               balance)
        "Insufficient funds")))
```

`make-withdraw` binds `balance` to its argument and returns a procedure it makes.  This procedure, when called:

1. binds `amount` to its argument;
2. compares `amount` with `balance` (which it can still see because it could see it when it was created);
3. if there's enough money then it mutates the `balance` binding, decrementing its value by the value of the `amount` binding, and returns the new value;
4. if there's not enough money it returns `"Insuficient funds"` (but does *not* mutate the `balance` binding, so you can try again with a smaller amount: a real bank would probably suck some money out of the `balance` binding at this point as a fine).

Now

```
(define x (make-withdraw 100))
```

creates a binding for `x` whose value is one of the procedures described above: in that procedure `balance` is initially `100`.

```
(define (f y) (y 25))
```

`f` is a procedure (is the name of a binding whose value is a procedure, which, when called) which binds `y` to its argument and then calls it with an argument of `25`.

```
(f x)
```

So, `f` is called with `x`, `x` being (bound to) the procedure constructed above.  In `f`, `y` is bound to this procedure (not to a copy of it, to it), and this procedure is then called with an argument of `25`.  This procedure then behaves as described above, and the results are as follows:

```
> (f x)
75
> (f x)
50
> (f x)
25
> (f x)
0
> (f x)
"Insufficient funds"
```

Note that:

- no first-class objects are copied anywhere in this process: there is no 'copy' of a procedure created;
- no first-class objects are mutated anywhere in this process;
- bindings are created (and later become inacessible and so can be destroyed) in this process;
- one binding is mutated repeatedly in this process (once for each call);
- I have not anywhere needed to mention 'environments', which are just the set of bindings visible from a certain point in the code and I think not a very useful concept.

I hope this makes some kind of sense.

---

### A more elaborate version of the above code

Something you might want to be able to do is to back out a transaction on your account.  One way to do that is to return, as well as the new balance, a procedure which undoes the last transaction.  Here is a procedure which does that (this code is in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/)):

```
(define (make-withdraw/backout
         balance
         (insufficient-funds "Insufficient funds"))
  (λ (amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
        (let ((last-balance balance))
          (set! balance (- balance amount))
              (values balance
                      (λ ()
                       (set! balance last-balance)
                       balance)))
            (values
             insufficient-funds
             (λ () balance)))))
```

When you make an account with this procedure, then calling it returns two values: the first is the new balance, or the value of `insufficient-funds` (defaultly `"Insufficient funds"`), the second is a procedure which will undo the transaction you just did.  Note that it undoes it by explicitly putting back the old balance, because you can't necessarily rely on `(= (- (+ x y) y) x)` being true in the presence of floating-point arithmetic I think.  If you understand how this works then you probably understand bindings.

Comment: @WillNess: thank you, I have fixed that.  There may be other gratuitous changes unfortunately as I smashed in a later version of it which I changed slightly after submitting it.

Comment: to the substance of it, I wanted to comment, that your answer just pushes the "magic" to *"bindings"* which are quite mysterious, somehow mutable, entities. the SICP implementation tries to clarify this, but it leaves the mutable *cons cells* as an unexplored mystery. so we must after all talk about a specific implementation. of course, the "normal" memory is settable quite naturally (like, array entries, in C, etc.)

Comment: @WillNess: yes, I think my aim (there's a paragraph about that now in fact) is to have some kind of minimum amount of magic: you need some, but I don't like all these extra layers of it (environments and frames) in SICP.  & bindings are almost tangible: you can make things which wrap a specific binding and allow you to set it even if you can't see it.  I was going to add that but the answer is already too long.

Comment: well, that's a matter of taste, but the authors' aim was to clarify things, I'm sure. And without environments, how are we to implement the interpreter? shallow binding seems much messier to implement the  lexical scoping with.

Comment: @WillNess: yes, definitely a matter of taste, I hope the answer makes that clear (now)

Comment: having bindings in mind is good too, as a higher-level abstraction. I'll re-read it now, for the additions. -- BTW have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888245/alan-kays-eval-apply-einstein-moment/34910496#34910496) (my) pseudocode rendition of the very first McCarthy evaluator? Environments are everywhere there. :)

Answer (score 2):

In case of pass by value, arguments to functions are evaluated and their values are bound to the function parameters.

So, if an argument is an expression, it is evaluated and the value is bound to the parameter. If it is an identifier bound to a value, that value is bound to the parameter.

If a value is simple, like an integer, that integer is “copied” in some memory cell allocated inside the new environment, if it is something more complex, like for instance a closure (a compiled function), you can think that the “reference” to that object is copied inside the new environment.

Comment: @OP a related concept is shallow copy vs deep copy of  a list structure for a possibly deeply-nested list. for example, Common Lisp's [copy-list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_lis.htm) only copies the top list structure. i.e. it creates a fresh chain of linked cons cells (nodes) and fills them with the contents of the nodes in the original, one by one. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf talks about this stuff  lot and has lots of diagrams as illustrations. ( :( ).

Comment: /talks about this stuff a lot and has lots of diagrams as illustrations./ --- the book's title is: "COMMON LISP:
A Gentle Introduction
to Symbolic Computation" by David Touretzky.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by value doesn't mean it isn't an address to an object, because it often is. C++ is a pass by value language. Here is an example of one property of pass by value:

```
(define (test x)
  (set! x 10))

(define y 20)
(test y)
```

The code above never changes `y` since `x` is a new binding that happen to point at the same value as `y` does and `(set! x 10)` makes `x` point to a different value. `y` will still be pointing at the original value `20`.

Now in `test` the value of `x` was changed so if you had other entry points that did other stuff with `x` then it would work as an object. This is how `make-withdraw` works.

```
(define x (make-withdraw 100))
```

The code above returns a closure it's top environment has `balanced` bound to `100` and when called with an amount it will `set!` the `balance` from it's clousure and then return the new value unless the funds are depleted.

```
(f x)
```

This makes a environment to hold `x`, which is the closure with its environments in tact, and the binding `x` disolves when the call is finished. It does not make a copy of `x`, but when `f` starts it never relies on what `x` is because it has passed the value, not the name. Thus `(f x)` is the same as calling `(x 25)` always. No change!