# Lexical or Dynamic scope - Haskell implemented evaluator

Tags: haskell, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

My professor has given us a question after talking about the difference between lexical and dynamic scope. He presented us a simple evaluator (of a fictional language) coded in Haskell. The following is the code:

```
type Var = ... 
type Env = ...
data Val = Vnum Int 
           | Vfun Var Exp 

data Exp = Enum Int
         | Evar Var
         | Efun Var Exp
         | Ecall Exp Exp
         | Elet Var Exp Exp

-- Predefined. Find the correspondent value of a variable
env_lookup :: Env -> Var -> Val
...

-- Predefined. Add the variable and its associated value to the environment
env_add :: Env -> Var -> Val -> Env
...

eval env (Enum n) = Vnum n
eval env (Evar x) = env_lookup x env
eval env (Ecall fun actual)
  = case (eval env fun) of
     Vnum n -> error "Not a Function!"
     Vfun formal body ->
           eval (env_add env formal (eval env actual)) body
-- To be completed --
```

The question asks:

> Does this implemented language use lexical scope or dynamic scope? And how should we change the code so it will has another type of scope

Frankly, this is a very hard question. It is easy to see, from the code, whether this language implements "call-by-name" or "call-by-value" (Which in this case, it is "call-by-value"). But analyzing whether it is dynamic or lexical scope is another story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is incomplete:

```
eval env (Ecall fun actual)
  = case fun of
     Vnum n -> error "Not a Function!"
     Vfun formal body ->
           eval (env_add env formal (eval     actual)) body
                                         ^^^^^
```

An argument is missing. But you have only one option to fix it, to add `env` there.

Then the meaning becomes, evaluate body in the environment `env` extended with pairings of parameters and arguments.

The *current* environment, `env`. Not the one from the time when the function was created.

This means dynamic scoping.

To fix it, we can use the `FUNARG` device: store the definitional environment together with body and formal parameters when the function (thus closure) is created. Then evaluate the body in the *definitional* environment extended as it is now with pairings of formal parameters and actual arguments evaluated in the *current* environment `env`.

See also: this relevant [answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888245/alan-kays-eval-apply-einstein-moment/34910496#34910496).

You can even have both dynamic and lexical scoping, making a plain lambda from, say, `(lambda ...)` forms, which will be evaluated under dynamic scoping, and making the closure of lambda and its definitional environment from, say, `(function (lambda ...))` forms (speaking in Lisp), for the lexical scoping. Thus having to handle both cases in  `eval`, like it is done in that other answer of mine, mentioned above.