# Lambda function translation

Tags: python, lambda

I have been struggling with a piece of python code that i can not make sense of.
It's about a nested lambda function that looks like this:

```
lambda l: lambda x: x[0] in [None if not i.object else i.object.key for i in l]
```

I have tried to translate it and i came up with this but i do not think this is right

```
 def f1(l):
     def f2(x):
           for i in l:
               if not i.object:
                  return None
               else
                  return x[0]
```

Comment: The translation is quite simple. If you have `lambda <arguments>: <body>` you have to replace it with `def name(<arguments):return <body>`. In the case where `body` is an other `lambda`, since you can't do `return def name ...` you just change it to: `def name2...; return name2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**

```
def f1(l):
    def f2(x):
        xs = [None if not i.object else i.object.key for i in l]
        return x[0] in xs
    return f2
```

**Step 2:**

```
def f1(l):
    def f2(x):
        xs = []
        for i in l:
            if not i.object:
                xs.append(None)
            else:
                xs.append(i.object.key)
        return x[0] in xs
    return f2
```

Comment: This is wrong.  `lambda`s return the value of their body. In this case the outer lambda returns the inner lambda, but these functions do not return any function... You should have `return f2` at the end of the definition of `f1`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from @citaret is fine but one aspect of this hasn't been made clear so far and that is - why is it we have a function in a function, why not just have `f1(l, x)`?

The answer is that the function is likely used as an input to another function which takes exactly 1 argument and therefore we wish to 'capture' the list `l` in the function so we need only supply `x` when we invoke the function (this is referred to as a 'closure').

So for example we can create a function `f` which takes a list `l` as input and returns a new function (a closure) over `l` which accepts `x` and return True if `x` is in `l`:

```
f = lambda l: lambda x: x in l
```

We can then create a function `f2` which is a closure over a list:

```
f2 = f([1, 2, 3])
```

Now we can map `f2` to another list:

```
print map(f2, [2, 3, 4])
```

Produces:

```
[True, True, False]
```

Python's `functools` module provides a [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function to help with this and perhaps make the intent of the inner lambda clearer, i.e. we could define `f3` as:

```
f3 = functools.partial(lambda l, x: x in l, [1, 2, 3])
print map(f3, [2, 3, 4])
```

For a more comprehensive description of closures see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures) answer.