# Python Lists and Local List declaration

Tags: python, list, localization

How to explicitly declare a list as a local variable that cannot be touched from anywhere except the function its declared in?

tried

```
LOCAL variable = []
```

doesnt work

Comment: A list in a function is local to the function

Comment: Maybe you should look into closures, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures

Comment: You might benefit from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/4788274)...

Answer (score 0):

Python is the interpreted language and it hasn't such statements.

Here is from the documentation:

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice

You can notice such `_pseudo_private_var`(one underscore) naming.It is just a convention, it just tells you SHOUDN'T touch this variable but you CAN change value of this one at the same time. It is a python). There is `__dynamic_obj_relative_naming` as well(two underscores).

More about scopes and namespaces rules you could find here [Classes, namespace and scope rules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private). There are few interesting statements you are interested in probably `global` and `nonlocal`. They are like opposites of yours.