# Enclosing functions scope search?

Tags: python, function

I am new to programming and skim read some topics on functions and classes. 
So after reading about fucntions and enclosing functions, I tried to mimic inheritance search in classes by only minipulating functions and its scope.

Example:

For the Code

```
def f1():
    t=1
    def f2(x):
        return eval(x)
    return f2
```

Why do I get a name error when doing

`f1()('t') #expecting 1 return`

But not when defining say

```
def f1():
    t=1
    def f2():
         return t
    return f2
```

`f()() # 1 is returned here`

I could solve this problem by defining t as nonlocal in the scope of f2, which mean that the first code only looks in the local scope of f2. Why does this happen? `

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425363/is-it-true-in-python-closure-will-be-stored-if-and-only-if-it-is-mentioned-lex)

Comment: Look at the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures - very nice explanation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the context for [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). By default, eval uses the locals and globals from the environment in which it is called. If we write:

```
def f1():
    t = 1

    def f2(x):
        return eval(x)
    return f2
```

then inside `f2`, `t` is not included in either the globals or locals and will therefore be inaccessible to the eval statement. Python will only add `t` to the locals for `f2` if `t` is actually used within `f2`. Thus, somewhat surprisingly, the following code *will* execute correctly:

```
def f1():
    t = 1

    def f2(x):
        print(t)
        return eval(x)
    return f2
```

since `t` is now used within `f2`. A better way of ensuring this always works is to do the following:

```
def f1():
    t = 1
    eval_globals = globals()
    eval_locals = locals()

    def f2(x):
        return eval(x, eval_globals, eval_locals)
    return f2
```

This overrides the context for eval, providing the globals and locals from within the scope of `f1`.

A caveat, since you mention that you're a new programmer: In general, you should avoid eval statements period unless you have a good reason for using them. There are better ways to achieve what you're doing here without resorting to an eval.