# how can i import global variable into other program

Tags: python

I have a function in a file example1.py which looks like:

```
def A():
    global var
    ....
    def B():
    .....
        return x
    #calculations using var,function B
    return var

def C(var):
....
    return something
```

I want to import all functions into other file example2.py using

```
from example1 import *
```

I see function A is working fine in example2.py  but function C is not returning the expected value. Whats wrong in my import?

Comment: Please show `example2.py` contents.

Comment: I would suggest that passing the results of functions around using globals is not the best way to work. Each function should take a number of arguments and return a result like you seem to have done using `return var`

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020419/1435475).

Answer (score 1):

You generally should avoid using globals to pass the results of functions between modules.

Consider the following example

**file1.py**

```
def add(num1,num2):
    var = num1 + num2
    return var
```

**main.py**

```
from file1 import add

result = add(5,6)
print(result)
```

The addition function inside file1.py is imported by main.py. main.py then uses that function and passes two arguments to it (5 and 6). `add` does the calculation and returns the result where it is then stored in `result` for further use in main.py.

This is a basic coding skill in any language and your question suggests that you should go through a number of python tutorials and fully understand them. Many other stack overflow users would not be so helpful as I have just been and expect you to know the basics of a language before asking questions.