# Class instance implementation, initializing instance - from SICP python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, sicp

I'm trying to the understand the initialization function in a python class system implementation, taken from this book [(SICP python - reference to book section)](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp12/book/objects.html#instances).

The `init_instance` (initialization) function `"""Return a new object with type cls, initialized with args."""` is where I'm having trouble. Below I've tried to narrow down my question, by explaining what I've understood.

```
def make_instance (cls): #good with this
    """return a new object instance, which is a dispatch dictionary"""
    def get_value(name):
        if name in attributes:
            return attributes[name]
        else:
            value = cls ['get'](name)
            return bind_method (value, instance)
    def set_value (name, value):
        attributes [name] = value
    attributes = {}
    instance = {'get': get_value, 'set': set_value}
    return instance

def bind_method (value, instance): #good with this
    """Return a bound method if value is callable, or value otherwise"""
    if callable (value):
        def method(*args):
            return value (instance, *args)
        return method
    else:
        return value

def make_class (attributes, base_class = None): 
    """Return a new class, which is a dispatch dictionary."""
    def get_value(name):
        if name in attributes:
            return attributes[name]
        elif base_class is not None:
            return base_class['get'](name)
    def set_value(name,value):
        attributes[name] = value
    def new(*args):
        return init_instance(cls, *args)
    cls = {'get':get_value,'set':set_value,'new':new}
    return cls

def init_instance(cls,*args): #problem here
    """Return a new object with type cls, initialized with args"""
    instance = make_instance (cls)
    init = cls ['get'] ('__init__')
    if init:                            
        init (instance, *args)          #No return function here
    return instance
```

Here is a call to above functions, to create a new class object called 'Jim'

```
def make_my_class():    #define a custom class
    pass
    return make_class({'__init__':__init__})   #return function that implements class

my_class = make_my_class()  #create a class
my_class_instance = my_class['new'] ('Jim') #create a class instance with ['new']
```

#### What I understand

Since this is an functional implementation of classes, the comparison is with inbuilt python classes. Below wherever I say Python Class/object/instance, I mean inbuilt.

- `make_instande(cls)` : takes the 'class' -> `cls` argument (a message fxn dictionary itself) and describes the behaviour of an object , i.e. provides required properties to behave in a similar way to a python object. We can set attributes, that stay local to attributes dictionary using '`set`'. Using `get`, if the attribute is not in object, it is looked up in class definition and a `bind_method` function is called.
- `bind_method(value,instance)`: binds a function in class definition to the object instance to emulate python methods in a python class instance. if value is not callable, returns value (python attribute from parent class).
- `make_class (attributes, base_class = None)`: Sets the behaviour of a class, with ability to inherit from another class. Uses get and set to in a similar fashion to make_instance, except, it doesn't require a bind_method. It uses `init_instance(cls, *args)` to create a new object instance with arbitrary number of arguments (for methods of the attributes). `cls` argument for `init_instance` passes class dispatch dictionary to the object instance. Hence, the object 'inherits' (for lack of a better word) the class features.
- `init_instance(cls, *args)`: Here I am a little unsure. Firstly, the function makes an instance with `instance = make_instance(cls)`, the instance inherits features of the class through `cls` dictionary. `init = cls['get']('__init__')` , `init` is created, a statement that looks up if `__init__` keyword was passed in attributes to `make_class`,  , `if init:    init(instance, *args)` makes args local to the instance? Returns an instance.

#### I can narrow down my question to -

`init_instance` is a return to `new(*args)` in `make_class`. Which means an instance dictionary is returned to `new(*args)`. However, `make_class` returns `cls` which means we have to update `cls` somehow to contain `instance` properties. How is that that being done? It's most likely this statement `init (instance, *args)` but I don't know how to break down this statement. I haven't seen `init` as fn, how are arguments being passed to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a little tricky, so it's not surprising that you find some of it puzzling. To understand it, you need to understand [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). There's some info about closures in Python in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20898085/4014959).

`init_instance` creates a new instance with `instance = make_instance(cls)`, then it looks up the `init` method of `cls`, and if it exists, it calls that `init` method with the new instance and whatever was passed in `args`. Neither `make_instance` nor `init_instance` modify the `cls` dictionary, or the `attributes` dictionary that was passed to `make_class` when `cls` was created. What actually happens is that each call of `make_instance` creates a new `attributes` dict for the instance it creates, which the `get` and `set` functions in the instance dict can reference.

Your `make_my_class` definition doesn't make much sense. It has a redundant `pass` statement, and `make_class({'__init__': __init__})` won't work because you haven't defined `__init__` anywhere, that needs to be a function which will initialize your class instances.

Here's a modified version of your code. I've created a simple `__init__` function for `my_class`, and added several `print` calls so we can get an idea of what the code's doing.

```
def hexid(obj):
    return hex(id(obj))

def make_instance(cls): # good with this
    """ Return a new object instance, which is a dispatch dictionary """
    def get_value(name):
        print('INSTANCE GET_VALUE', name, 'from', hexid(attributes))
        if name in attributes:
            return attributes[name]
        else:
            value = cls['get'](name)
            return bind_method(value, instance)

    def set_value(name, value):
        attributes[name] = value

    attributes = {'test': 'Default Test'}
    print('Created instance attributes', hexid(attributes))
    instance = {'get': get_value, 'set': set_value}
    return instance

def bind_method(value, instance): # good with this
    """ Return a bound method if value is callable, or value otherwise """
    if callable(value):
        def method(*args):
            return value(instance, *args)
        return method
    else:
        return value

def make_class(attributes, base_class=None): 
    """ Return a new class, which is a dispatch dictionary. """
    def get_value(name):
        print('\nCLASS GET_VALUE', name, 'from', hexid(attributes))
        if name in attributes:
            return attributes[name]
        elif base_class is not None:
            return base_class['get'](name)

    def set_value(name, value):
        attributes[name] = value

    def new(*args):
        return init_instance(cls, *args)

    print('Creating class with attributes', hexid(attributes))
    cls = {'get': get_value, 'set': set_value, 'new': new}
    return cls

def init_instance(cls, *args): # problem here
    """ Return a new object with type cls, initialized with args """
    instance = make_instance(cls)
    init = cls['get']('__init__')
    if init:
        print('Calling init of', hexid(cls), 'on', hexid(instance), 'with', args)
        init(instance, *args)          #No return here
    return instance

def make_my_class(): # define a custom class
    # Create a simple __init__ for the class
    def __init__(inst, *args):
        print('INIT', hexid(inst), args)
        inst['set']('data', args)

    # return a dict that implements class
    return make_class({'__init__': __init__})

# test

#create a class
my_class = make_my_class()

#create some class instances
jim = my_class['new']('Jim')
jim['set']('test', 'Hello')

fred = my_class['new']('Fred') 

print('CLASS', hexid(my_class))
print('\nINSTANCE', hexid(jim))
print(jim['get']('data'))
print(jim['get']('test'))

print('\nINSTANCE', hexid(fred))
print(fred['get']('data'))
print(fred['get']('test'))
```

**output**

```
Creating class with attributes 0xb71e67d4
Created instance attributes 0xb71373ec

CLASS GET_VALUE __init__ from 0xb71e67d4
Calling init of 0xb7137414 on 0xb71373c4 with ('Jim',)
INIT 0xb71373c4 ('Jim',)
Created instance attributes 0xb7137374

CLASS GET_VALUE __init__ from 0xb71e67d4
Calling init of 0xb7137414 on 0xb713734c with ('Fred',)
INIT 0xb713734c ('Fred',)
CLASS 0xb7137414

INSTANCE 0xb71373c4
INSTANCE GET_VALUE data from 0xb71373ec
('Jim',)
INSTANCE GET_VALUE test from 0xb71373ec
Hello

INSTANCE 0xb713734c
INSTANCE GET_VALUE data from 0xb7137374
('Fred',)
INSTANCE GET_VALUE test from 0xb7137374
Default Test
```

Comment: this was very helpful. The references are excellent as well. I didn't know about free variables. I'll be using print() and local() and other techniques that were referred to in this answer.