# How a method call works in Python, and significance of bound methods

Tags: python, function, class, object, methods

I have a basic question on how a method call really works in Python. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848237/clarification-on-a-paragraph-in-the-python-tutorial-documentation) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static) that are helpful, but not answering all my questions.

Basically, my understanding from [Section 9.3.4 of Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) is that:

When an ***instance object*** calls its method, a search is done on the ***class object***. If the matching function is found, the ***function object*** attached to the ***class object*** is called with the ***instance object*** as its first parameter.

My main questions are:

- What is the significance of bound methods? Currently, a call to method is transferred to a call to function with the **instance object** as its first argument enabling the function to access the **instance object**. Why has Python adopted this approach, instead of each method directly processing its bound **instance object**? Any cons and pros for each of these approaches?
- Can a bound method theoretically lead to a lower performance (slower execution), in case that a large number of instances call their own method simultaneously, which is seemingly equivalent to calling one single **function object** multiple times (in a serial fashion??) with different instances as the first argument per call?

I know I am missing some fundamentals here, and I would be grateful if anyone could please advise. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You skipped a step in what actually happens. Let's say you try to call `foo.bar(baz)`, where `foo` is an instance of `Foo`.

1. First, an instance attribute named `bar` is looked for in the object `foo`. Most likely, it doesn't exist, as you typically don't want to shadow the actual method like this.
2. Next, `bar` is looked for as a class attribute in each class in the MRO of `foo`. For simplicity, assume you find it right away in `Foo`.
3. At this point, `Foo.bar` is a simple `function` object. But, because a `function` implements the descriptor protocol, you don't actually get the `function` object itself: you get the result of `Foo.bar.__get__(foo, Foo)`. *That* result is the bound method: an instance of `method` which wraps both the original function and the object `foo`. (For a better description of what is going on, see [the descriptor protocol how-to guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).
4. Calling an instance of `method` causes the underlying function to be called, with `foo` as the first argument and `baz` as an additional object. Whatever the function returns is what the `method` instance returns.

This is how `foo.bar(baz)` becomes `Foo.bar(foo, baz)`, by way of `Foo.bar.__get__(foo, Foo)(baz)`.

Although there is some additional overhead, it's not really significant compared to the benefit of having many different things simply be applications of the descriptor protocol. All of the following are implemented via descriptors, without having to add specific implementations of each to the language itself:

1. Instance methods
2. Class methods
3. Static methods
4. Properties

as well as the descriptor protocol being something you can implement in your *own* classes in order to provide specific behavior in a way that blends seamlessly with other Python conventions.

Comment: In step 2, did you mean "__bar__ is looked for as a class attribute in each class in the MRO of foo"?