# How to open a closure in python?

Tags: python, closures

I came accross the following interview question and have no idea how to solve it:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair
```

Given a pair, e.g `cons(6,8)` I am requested to return `a` and `b` separetely, e.g in this case 6, 8 respectively.

Meaning, for example,

```
def first(pair):
    pass
    #would return pair's `a` somehow

def second(pair):
    pass
    #would return pair's `b` somehow
```

How can this be done?

Comment: what do you mean by "to return separately"?

Comment: This may help you understand closures better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures

Comment: so you wan just "a" to be returned, or you want also another function to return the second one?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 I want to understand the concept. It is the same, but I edited again to also have the second one, for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
pair = cons(6, 8)

def first(pair):
    return  pair(lambda x, y: x)

def second(pair):
    return  pair(lambda x, y: y)

print(first(pair))
print(second(pair))

# ouput:
# 6
# 8
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `cons` takes two arguments, `a` and `b`, and returns a function that takes one argument, `f`.  The returned function is a closure, since it contains references to `a` and `b` which would otherwise be out of scope when `cons` returns.

The returned function takes a function argument, calls it with `a` and `b`, and returns the result.

For example, if you do:

```
func = cons(6, 8)
```

Then you can do:

```
def g(a, b):
    return a

func(g)
```

This will return `6`.  Similarly, if you define `g` to return `b`, then `func` would return `8`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
c = cons(6, 8)
a = c.__closure__[0].cell_contents
b = c.__closure__[1].cell_contents

print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a lambda uses `iter(args)` to make the args passed into `cons` iterable. Then, the caller can use `next(it)` to access individual elements:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

it = cons(6, 8)(lambda *args: iter(args))
print(next(it)) # => 6
print(next(it)) # => 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an indexed item it is a task for `getitem`.

```
from operator import getitem
item0 = cons(6, 8)(lambda *v: getitem(v, 0))
item1 = cons(6, 8)(lambda *v: getitem(v, 1))
```

or

```
from operator import getitem
func = cons(6, 8)
item0 = func(lambda *v: getitem(v, 0))
item1 = func(lambda *v: getitem(v, 1))
```