# Does Python closure require the outer scope going out of scope(i.e. ended)

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

As explain in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures) `A closure occurs when a function has access to a local variable from an enclosing scope that has finished its execution`. As I understand a function scope is finished when it returns. Several books on python closure always have examples on closure defining a nested function and returning it at the end to signify the ending of the outer scope. Such as `Fluent Python` by Ramalho

```
def make_averager():
    series = []
    def averager(new_value):
        series.append(new_value)
        total = sum(series)
        return total/len(series)
    return averager
```

Book `Introducing Python` by Lubanovic

```
def knights2(saying):
    def inner2():
        return "We are the knights who say: '%s'" % saying
    return inner2
```

I then stumble upon the book `Effective Python` by Brett Slatkin. His example of closure:

```
def sort_priority(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return (0, x)
        return (1, x)
    values.sort(key=helper)

numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = {2, 3, 5, 7}
sort_priority(numbers, group)
```

Brett says closure happen in `helper` function. `helper` got called inside of `values.sort(key=helper)`. As I understand the scope of `sort_priority` has not ended when it reaches to the line `values.sort(key=helper)`. Why does he say closure occurring here?

I only wonder about the closure aspect of Brett's example. I already know/understand how `sort_priority` and `helper` work

Pearson provides  [the sample pages of the book here](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780134034287/samplepages/9780134034287.pdf). Luckily, sample pages have the part I mentioned. It is `Item 15: Know How Closures Interact with Variable Scope`

Comment: I don’t worry about such things. What is in a name? A closure by any other name would be just as functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand the scope of `sort_priority` has not ended when it
>   reaches to the line `values.sort(key=helper)`. Why does he say closure
>   occurring here?

Supposing that it is not an outright mistake, Slatkin must be using a different definition of "closure".  Since the code presented is an example, I presume it accompanies a definition, which you should compare carefully with the one you quoted.

I suppose that Slatkin's idea revolves around `helper()` being able to access the `group` variable of the surrounding context when it is called by `values.sort()`, where that variable is not in scope.  This is at least akin to the conventional definition of a closure -- the function carries with it the ability to reference data belonging to the context of its definition.  I don't think I would agree that it fully meets the usual criteria for a closure, but do not let that distract you from the essence of the technique that Slatkin is trying to teach.

Comment: Following the that example he states 3 reasons: `Python supports closures: functions that refer to variables from the scope in which they were defined. This is why the helper function is able to access the group argument to sort_priority.......This is why the return value from the
helper closure causes the sort order to have two distinct groups.`. It is `Item 15: Know How Closures Interact with Variable Scope`. Pearson provides sample pages of the book here: https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780134034287/samplepages/9780134034287.pdf.

Comment: Brett's follow-ups from that example indicates that he meant closure happened in `helper`, so I don't think he is mistaken. His analysis is thoughtful, but this closure part is bugging me and makes me doubt my understanding of closure. I really wish his definition of closure is consistent with others because I really like his book. Thanks for the answer. I wait for a few days to see any different insights. Upvoted :) +1

Comment: So, just as I said: Slatkin is using a definition of closure that is slightly more broad than the one you referenced, and he presents it in the book.  And he is referring to `helper()` being able to access variables from the context of its definition when it is called from a place where they are out of scope.  I note that this is consistent with [the Wikipedia definition of the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).  I'm afraid it's not unusual for the same word to be defined a bit differently by different people.