# Using LogRecordFactory in python to add custom fields for logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am trying to add a custom field in my logging using `LogRecordFactory`.  I am repeatedly calling a class and every time I do that, I want to set the custom_attribute in the init module so the remainder of the code within the class will have this attribute.  But I cannot get this to work.  I found the following which works, but its static.

```
import logging

old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.custom_attribute = "whatever"
    return record



logging.basicConfig(format="%(custom_attribute)s - %(message)s")
logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("test")
```

This will output correctly:

```
whatever - test
```

However, my use case is that the custom_attribute will vary.  Every time I call a specific function, I want to change this.  So it seems like record_factory needs another parameter passed to it so it can then return the correct record with the new parameter.  But I cant figure it out.  I have tried adding a parameter to the function, but when I make the call I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'name', 'level', 'pathname', 'lineno', 'msg', 'args', and 'exc_info'
```

I think this has something to do with the `*args` and `**kwargs` but I don't really know.  Also, why are there no parenthesis after `record_factory` when its called by `logging.setLogRecordFactory`?  I have never seen a function work like this.

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020443/8583496):

```
import logging

old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def record_factory_factory(context_id):
    def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
        record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
        record.custom_attribute = context_id
        return record
    return record_factory


logging.basicConfig(format="%(custom_attribute)s - %(message)s")
logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory_factory("whatever"))
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("test")

logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory_factory("whatever2"))
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug("test")
```

result:

```
$ python3 log_test.py                                                          
whatever - test
whatever2 - test
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question while I was trying to do something similar. This is how I solved it, assuming that you want to add something called xyz to every log line (further explanation below):

```
import logging
import threading
 

thread_local = threading.local()
 

def add_xyz_to_logrecords(xyz):
    factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()
    if isinstance(factory, XYZLogFactory):
        factory.set_xyz(xyz)
    else:
        logging.setLogRecordFactory(XYZLogFactory(factory, xyz))
 

class XYZLogFactory():
    def __init__(self, original_factory, xyz):
        self.original_factory = original_factory
        thread_local.xyz = xyz

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        record = self.original_factory(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            record.xyz = thread_local.xyz
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return record

   def set_xyz(self, xyz):
        thread_local.xyz = xyz
```

Here I've created a callable class XYZLogFactory, that remembers what the current value of xyz is, and also remembers what the original LogRecordFactory was. When called as a function, it creates a record using the original LogRecordFactory, and adds an xyz attribute with the current value.
The thread_local is to make it thread-safe, but for an easier version, you could just use an attribute on the XYZLogFactory:

```
class XYZLogFactory():
    def __init__(self, original_factory, xyz):
        self.original_factory = original_factory
        self.xyz = xyz

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        record = self.original_factory(*args, **kwargs)
        record.xyz = self.xyz
        return record

   def set_xyz(self, xyz):
        self.xyz = xyz
```

In my very first attempt (not shown here), I did not store the original factory, but stored it implicitly in the new LogRecordFactury using a closure. However, after a while that led to a RecursionError, because it kept calling the previous factory, which called the previous factory, etc.

Regarding your last question: there are no parentheses because the function is not called here. Instead it's passed to the logging.setLogRecordFactory, which saves it in a variable somewhere, and then calls that someplace else. If you want more information you can google something like 'functions as first class citizens'.
Easy example:

```
x = str  # Assign to x the function that gives string representation of object
x(1)  # outputs the string representation of 1, same as if you'd called str(1)
> '1'
```