# Can anybody explain about the closure of function in Python?

Tags: python, closures, higher-order-functions

#### Python

Can anyone help me to understand this code, I am new to Python, how does this function work?

```
    def makeInc(x):
        def inc(y):

            return y + x
        return inc
    incOne = makeInc(1)
    incFive = makeInc(5)
    print(incOne(5)) # returns 6
    print(incFive(5)) # returns 10
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps [Why aren't python nested functions called closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures) (for Python 2 but the argument should apply to Python 3).

Comment: Your makeInc function return inc function as value so when you call first function as incOne = makeInc(1) it sets value of x as 1 and return you inc function to call from incOne var again when you call incOne(5) it sets y =5 and compute the sum of x and y and return the value. It’s called nested functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Higher-order functions

---

Functions like `makeInc` that in turn, return another function are called [higher order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). Usually, functions are known to accept data as input and return data as output. With higher order functions, functions instead of data, either return code as output or accept code as input. This code is wrapped into a function. In Python, functions are first class citizens which means functions, just like data, can be passed around. For instance:

```
myvariable = print
```

Notice, how I have assigned `print` to `myvariable` and how I have dropped the parentheses after `print` Functions without parentheses are called function objects. This means `myvariable` now is just another name for `print`:

```
print("Hello World!")
myvariable("Hello World!")
```

Both of the above statements do the exact same thing. What can be assigned to variables can also be returned from functions:

```
def myfunction():
    return print


myfunction()("Hello World!");
```

---

Now let's look at your example:

```
def makeInc(x):
    def inc(y):

        return y + x
    return inc
```

`makeInc` is a function that accepts a parameter called `x`. It then defines another nested inner function called `inc` which takes in a parameter called `y`. The thing about nested functions is that they have access to the variables of the enclosing function as well. Here, `inc` is the inner function but it has access to `x` which is a variable of the enclosing outer scope.
The last statement `return inc` returns the inner function to the caller of `makeInc`. What `makeInc` essentially is doing, is creating a custom function based on the parameter it receives.
For instance:

```
x = makeInc(10)
```

`makeInc` will first accept 10 and then return a function that takes in an argument `y` and it increments `y` by 10.
Here, `x` is a function that takes in any argument `y` and then increments it by 10:

```
x(42) # Returns 52
```

#### `nonlocal`

However, there is a caveat when using nested functions:

```
def outer():
    x = 10
    def inner():
       x = 20
    inner() 
    print(x) # prints 10
```

Here, you would assume that the last `print` statement will print 20. But no! When you assign `x = 20` in the inner function, it creates a new local variable called `x` which is initialized to 20. The outer `x` remains untouched. To modify the outer `x`, use the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def outer():
    x = 10
    def inner():
       nonlocal x = 20
    inner()
    print(x) # prints 20
```

If you are directly reading `x` inside `inner()` instead of assigning to it, you do not need `nonlocal`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that `makeInc()` returns a function handle pointing to specific implementation of `inc()`. So, calling `makeInc(5)` "replaces" the `x` in `inc(y)` to `5` and returns the callable handle of that function. This handle is saved in `incFive`. You can now call the function as defined (`inc(y)`). Since you set x=5 before, the result will be `y+5`.