# How does Python decorator work under the hood?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I have some questions regarding what happens inside decorators in Python.

1. Consider code, which saves sum in log file:

```
def logger(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(result))
            
        return result
    return wrapped        
        
@logger
def summator(numlist):
    return sum(numlist)

print(f"Summator: {summator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])}")
```

How does it work when I run `summator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`? I suppose the `logger` to send the `summator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` function instance inside `wrapped`, where the `summator` function is executed and it's result is someway modified. But `def logger(func)` is strange for me: does it mean, that it takes **`func` with `func` arguments attached**? I see that `logger` itself doesn't take `* args, ** kwargs`, only `wrapped` does...

2. Consider similar code:

```
def logger(filename):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(result))
            
            return result
        return wrapped
    return decorator

        
@logger('new_log.txt')
def summator(numlist):
    return sum(numlist)
```

How does `decorator` get `func`? It is wrapped by `logger`, which accepts only a filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my simple explanation of how decorators work.

You are going to *decorate* a function, here `summator` and basically add some functionalities to it without touching the body of it.

The expression:

```py
@logger
def summator(numlist):
    return sum(numlist)
```

is equivalent to:

```py
def summator(numlist):
    return sum(numlist)

summator = logger(summator)
```

`@` is just a syntactic sugar.

What happened?
Look at `logger` function. What does it do ? it takes a **function** and returns another **function** (here named `wrapped`). Not the result of that function, just the function itself.

Then you assign this *returned function* from calling `logger(summator)` to a symbol called `summator`. From now on, whenever you call `summator` you are calling the returned function from the `logger`. You are calling the `wrapped`.

Inside `wrapped` there is a `func`. What is it ? isn't it the original `summator` function which you passed to the `logger` in the previous paragraph? YES.

Q: How `wrapped` function can access it? it is not its local variable!
A: Because `wrapped` is a closure and have access to the enclosing scope's local variables. [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020443/13944524)

So `wrapped` calls `func`, stores the result, write it to the file then returns it.

**note**: we normally define our `wrapped` function with this signature : `def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):` because we want to be free to pass all parameters(both positional and keyword arguments) down to the `func` function. At the end of the day `func` and original `summator` are the same object. In your case you could write it like:

```py
def logger(func):
    def wrapped(lst):       # <--------
        result = func(lst)  # <--------
        with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(result))

        return result
    return wrapped
```

---

You second question is referring to what is known as *decorator factory*. It's a function which returns the actual decorator. **Q:** When do we use it? **A:** When we want to have additional parameters from the decorator factory to the decorator or it's inner function. (Here you passed `filename` as a parameter to the decorator factory but used it inside the `wrapped` function.)

The story is the same, it is just another layer above our decorator. The equivalent of that syntactic sugar would be:

```py
def summator(numlist):
    return sum(numlist)

summator = logger('new_log.txt')(summator)

# In two steps, it would be:
# decorator = logger('new_log.txt')
# summator = decorator(summator)
```

**note**: In the first question, name `logger` was the actual decorator(Because it takes the `summator` function for decorating) But in second question it is not. It is now a decorator factory.

The way `wrapped` can access `filename` is the same way it can access `func` as I mentioned previously.

Read more about it [here](http://concisionandconcinnity.blogspot.com/2010/09/decorator-factories-and-decorator.html).

Comment: Thank you, now that's clear for me!