# Python function issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i am a beginner who is learning Python, i have stumbled across this example in a book and for some reason when i attempt the same code myself i am not receiving the same output? Please help...

```
def tester(start):
    state = start
    def nested(label):
        nonlocal state
        print(label, state)
        state += 1
    return nested

>>> F = tester(0)
>>> F('spam')
spam 0
>>> F('ham')
ham 1
>>> F('eggs')
eggs 2
```

My results are not incrementing + 1 each time i run the function, is there something wrong with the book?

Comment: What output are _you_ getting?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running that with Python 2.x?

Comment: @Keith it doesn't work at all in Python 2.x (throws error at `nonlocal state`). Anyway I tried it in terminal, it works fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Works for me](http://ideone.com/Q2JaD). Are you sure you're using python 3? `nonlocal` is a python 3 feature, and will *not* work in python 2.x.

Comment: How do you know if you are using python 3? i just run python interactively in my terminal by typing 'python'? or do you need to run it differently for python 3? i do have python 3.2 installed.

Comment: @user1265535: When you open up your Python Terminal, the first line has the version listed for eg. `Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Comment: yeah okay my bad it works in terminal now which is weird Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1261961/778858 sums it up. Basically python changed a lot from 2.~ to 3.0 >= and you end up with issues like this. Compare what it says at the start of the book with the version they are using and compare it to your own.