# Immediately enclosing namespace of a top-level function (for the purpose of parsing nonlocal)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused by the behavior of python's `nonlocal` keyword.

So the standard example is as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement): there is a `def outerfoo():` block containing a variable definition `outvar = 0`, and inside `outerfoo()` there is a `def innerfoo():` block containing `nonlocal outvar`, making it so that the value of `outvar` in `outerfoo():`'s namespace can be changed by what goes on inside `innerfoo()`.

So far so good. However, the following code fails with a `SyntaxError`:

```
outvar = 0 #not in any function
def foo():
    nonlocal outvar
    outvar += 1
foo()
```

What namespace is the parser looking in, that it is not finding `outvar`?

Comment: `nonlocals` are used inside functions that are inside functions, in your example you should use `global outvar`.

Comment: I know that `global outvar` will work. My question, which was not answered in [Python nonlocal statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement), is why a variable binding in the top-level or main scope is not recognized as the intended binding for a `nonlocal` statement in a top-level `def` block.

Similarly, [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) does not specify that `nonlocal` only works in functions defined inside other functions.