# why this python program have the following output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-nonlocal

```
def makeInc (x, step):
    def next():
        nonlocal x, step
        x = x + step
        return x
    return next

x = makeInc (0, 1)
y = makeInc (0, 10)

x1=x()
x2=x()
y1=y()
y2=y()

print( x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

The output is 1 2 10 20. 
I am not sure why it gives these outputs, can anyone explain it in detail? Thanks!

Comment: Throws syntax errors.

Comment: @Hariprasad it worked correctly for me.  I'm using Python 3.3.1, which version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement / keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement-keyword) and [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `makeInc()` is a "factory" that makes function objects and returns them.  The `nonlocal` declaration makes the function "close over" a variable.  Usually you would make an explicit variable and close over that; in this case, the nonlocal declaration is closing over an argument variable from `makeInc()`.

If you want to learn about closures and `nonlocal` here are a few references:

http://www.mondoinfo.com/blog/C182263547/E20060918200706/index.html

[Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)

So, `makeInc()` makes a function object that has a start value and a "step" by which the start value will be incremented.  Once you have made the custom function object, the final code calls the functions and gets the incrementing values.