# Python: Variables are still accessible if defined in try or if?

Tags: python, scope

I'm a Python beginner and I am from C/C++ background. I'm using Python 2.7.

I read this article: [A Beginner’s Guide to Python’s Namespaces, Scope Resolution, and the LEGB Rule](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/12/a-beginners-guide-to-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-and-the-legb-rule/), and I think I have some understanding of Python's these technologies.

Today I realized that I can write Python code like this:

```
if condition_1:
    var_x = some_value
else:
    var_x = another_value
print var_x
```

That is, var_x is still accessible even it is **not** define **before** the if. Because I am from C/C++ background, this is something new to me, as in C/C++, `var_x` are defined in the scope enclosed by if and else, therefore you cannot access it any more unless you define `var_x` before `if`.

I've tried to search the answers on Google but because I'm still new to Python, I don't even know where to start and what keywords I should use.

My guess is that, in Python, `if` does not create new scope. All the variables that are newly defined in `if` are just in the scope that `if` resides in and this is why the variable is still accessible after the `if`. However, if `var_x`, in the example above, is only defined in `if` but not in `else`, a warning will be issued to say that the `print var_x` may reference to a variable that may not be defined.

I have some confidence in my own understanding. However, **could somebody help correct me if I'm wrong somewhere, or give me a link of the document that discusses about this??**

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct. Variables defined in `if`/`elif`/`else` blocks are visible in the scope containing the block.

Comment: This also applies to `for` and `while` loops, as well as the `with` statement. Basically everything but functions and classes (you can still access variables through the class's name: `Cls.var`).

Comment: you can mess around looking at what is and isn't in scope with `locals()` and `globals()`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen you are correct. However, there are other enclosed scopes, such as comprehensions, where variables created in them are not visible to the surrounding code.

Comment: @MattDMo Good point.

Comment: @MattDMo: true only for Python 3.x. With 2.x comprehension variables are defined in the surrounding scope.

Comment: brackets = whitespace characters left
Always can access if calling elements is stay left side .

Comment: @Daniel interesting, I didn't know that

Comment: @MattDMo: I tried what Daniel said about comprehension variables in Python 2.7, and it's true. With the code `a = [n for n in range(0,10)]`, `print n`, you'll see `n` is still accessible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My guess is that, in Python, `if` does not create new scope. All the variables that are newly defined in `if` are just in the scope that if resides in and this is why the variable is still accessible after the `if`.

That is correct. In Python, [namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), that essentially decide about the variable scopes, are only created for modules, and functions (including methods; basically any `def`). So everything that happens within a function (and not in a sub-function) is placed in the same namespace.

It’s important to know however that the mere existance of an assignment within a function will reserve a name in the local namespace. This makes for some interesting situations:

```
def outer ():
    x = 5
    def inner ():
        print(x)
        # x = 10
    inner()
outer()
```

In the code above, with that line commented out, the code will print `5` as you may expect. That’s because `inner` will look in the outer scope for the name `x`. If you add the line `x = 10` though, the name `x` will be *local* to `inner`, so the *earlier* look up to `x` will look in the local namespace of `inner`. But since it hasn’t been assigned yet, you will receive an `UnboundLocalError` (*“local variable 'x' referenced before assignment”*). The [`nonlocal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement) statement was added in Python 3 to overcome one issue from this: The situation where you want to actually modify the `x` of the outer scope within the inner function.

For more information on name lookup, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

Comment: Thanks, and it's interesting to know the situation you mentioned here.. I've never known about this!