# Python for loop, global vs local

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Beginner here, trying to understand for loops using Python3. Can someone please explain in the following code why outside of the for loop returns a value of 5? Does Python just return the max number if a variable is called outside of the for loop?

```
for x in range(0,6):
    print(x) #here is the expected output of (0,1,2,3,4,5)

print(x) #this just returns 5, why?
```

Comment: Python retains the last value of a variable used in a loop. Try to play around with the values inside range.

Comment: Nice question! I thought this would have given you an error, because `x` should be a local variable to the loop, but apparently it is not garbage collected immediately.

Comment: @nbro for loops don’t create a new scope. This has nothing to do with garbage collection, the variable is defined for the whole namespace (functions and modules). See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31505354/216074).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: "Does Python just return the max number if a variable is called outside of the for loop?" It retains the **last** value, because **nothing happened that could have changed the value**. The purpose of names is to remember and refer to stuff. If the name is expected to be *usable at all*, then there is no other candidate for what it could be naming. So the only remaining question is "why is the name still in use after the `for` loop?" and answer is that `for` loops in Python do not create a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) (emphasis mine):

> The for-loop makes **assignments to the variables(s) in the target list**. This overwrites all previous assignments to those variables including those made in the suite of the for-loop:
>
> […]
>
> Names in the target list are **not deleted when the loop is finished**, but if the sequence is empty, they will not have been assigned to at all by the loop.

So while you are iterating over the range of numbers from 0 to 6, those values are assigned to `x` in each iteration. So in the first iteration, you get `x = 0`, in the second it’s `x = 1`, and so on until `x = 5` (which is the last number that’s in the range).

Then when the for loop ends, as specified, the variable `x` is *not deleted*, so `x` is still around and still has that value `5` that it was assigned to in the final iteration.

---

Finally, since you seemed surprised that `x` is *just* 5 in the end (and not `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`), note that in each iteration, `x` has only a single value. The `print(x)` inside the for loop is just executed 6 times with `x` having a different value each time. That does not result in the output you stated though; it’s still one number per line. Your code is essentially the same as the following without loops:

```
# the for loop does this:
x = 0
print(x)
x = 1
print(x)
x = 2
print(x)
x = 3
print(x)
x = 4
print(x)
x = 5
print(x)

# and this follows the loop:
print(x)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation poke. Very appreciated, thanks!