# Pass name to nested function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What (if anything) is actually different between using a name in a nested function and passing a name to a nested function? If there's no difference, which is preferred by convention?

```
def foo(bar):
    def put():
        bar.append('World!')
        print(', '.join(bar))
    put()
foo(['Hello'])
```

versus

```
def foo(bar):
    def put(bar):
        bar += ['World!']
        print(', '.join(bar))
    put(bar)
foo(['Hello'])
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement

Comment: As the Zen of Python dictates, "Explicit is better than implicit.". In this case, explicitly passing the argument is clearer than having to guess where `bar` suddenly came from.

Comment: Are you only talking about nested functions, and not closures? Meaning, are you not intending to return `put` as the return value of `foo`?

Comment: @Cyphase I am not talking about closures, unless that influences the choice between the alternatives. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Ian, I'll say upfront that I agree with @Wolph that explicit is better than implicit. That said though, is there a reason you need a nested function at all as opposed to defining it on it's own? That's the better option IMO.

Comment: @Cyphase Reason: it seems to me that defining `put` in the global scope, while only using it in `foo` is akin to `put` suddenly appearing. I guess "sudden" is subjective.

Comment: @Ian, using `put` somewhere else as well doesn't make it any less 'sudden' of an appearance in `foo`. I realize this is probably a made-up example, but in this case and many others, you don't even need a `put` function; just put the code for the `put` function directly in `bar`. Could you show an example closer to your actual usage?

Comment: @Ian, did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the first one, bar variable is in a scope of the parent function, it can be used in the child function , unless you do assignment on it (This would be the case something similar to using `global` variables in function) . Example -

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     def put():
...         bar = bar + ['World']
...         print(', '.join(bar))
...     put()
...
>>>
>>> foo(['Hello'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in foo
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in put
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
```

In this case if you want to use the `bar` and assign to it as well, you need to use the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword , Example -

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     def put():
...         nonlocal bar
...         bar = bar + ['World!']
...         print(', '.join(bar))
...     put()
...
>>> foo(['Hello'])
Hello, World!
```

---

Whereas in the second one, bar is a local variable to the `put()` function (because its an argument to it) and can be assigned without the above `UnboundLocalError` , Example -

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     def put(bar):
...         bar = bar + ['World!']
...         print(', '.join(bar))
...     put(bar)
...
>>>
>>> foo(['Hello'])
Hello, World!
```

I would prefer explicitly passing the required arguments as done in the second case.

Comment: If you don't assign to `bar` in the second case (either by using `bar.append` or `+=`) then `bar` is not local, right? Its value will change in the scope of foo after `put(bar)` as well. So in my snippets ... effectively no difference?

Comment: in second case, bar is always local to the inner function, irrespective of whether you assign or not. But yes in your particular example, bar being local or not , does not really make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only talking about nested functions, and not closures, unless you have a specific reason to have it be nested, I would recommend defining each function in the module scope:

```
def put(bar):
    bar += ['World!']
    print(', '.join(bar))


def foo(bar):
    put(bar)


foo(['Hello'])
```

If for some reason you do need it to be nested, it's better to pass in `bar` explicitly. However, if you do think you need it to be nested, ask about your reasoning first; there's a good chance that you don't. :)