# What is the difference between non local variable and global variable?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, programming-languages, python-nonlocal

I'm learning the concepts of programming languages.

I found the terminology "nonlocal" in python syntax.

What is the meaning of nonlocal in python?

Comment: See https://www.smallsurething.com/a-quick-guide-to-nonlocal-in-python-3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement / keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement-keyword)

Comment: also they are generally considered poor style.

Answer (score 29):

The nonlocal variables are present in a nested block. A keyword nonlocal is used and the value from the nearest enclosing block is taken. For example:

```py
def outer():
    x = "local"
    
    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x = "nonlocal"
        print("inner:", x)
    
    inner()
    print("outer:", x)
```

The output will be "nonlocal" both the times as the value of x has been changed by the inner function.

Comment: Don't you mean "block" or "scope" rather than "loop"? There are no loops in this example.

Answer (score 19):

"nonlocal" means that a variable is "neither local or global", i.e, the variable is from an enclosing namespace (typically from an outer function of a nested function).

An important difference between nonlocal and global is that a nonlocal variable must have been already bound in the enclosing namespace (otherwise an syntaxError will be raised) while a global declaration in a local scope does not require the variable is pre-bound (it will create a new binding in the global namespace if the variable is not pre-bound).

Answer (score 16):

`nonlocal foo` in `inner()` can access **the non-local variable `foo = 10`** in `middle()` but not **the non-local variable `foo = 5`** in `outer()` or **the global variable `foo = 0`** outside `outer()` as shown below:

```py
foo = 0 # <- ✖
def outer():
    foo = 5 # <- ✖
    def middle():
        foo = 10 # <- 〇
        def inner():
            nonlocal foo # Here
            foo += 1
            print(foo) # 11
        inner()
    middle()
outer()
```

`global foo` in `inner()` can access **the global variable `foo = 0`** outside `outer()` but not **the non-local variable `foo = 5`** in `outer()` and `middle()` as shown below:

```py
foo = 0 # <- 〇
def outer():
    foo = 5 # <- ✖
    def middle():
        foo = 10 # <- ✖
        def inner():
            global foo # Here
            foo += 1
            print(foo) # 1
        inner()
    middle()
outer()
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) about nonlocal statements:

> The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to
> previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope. This is
> important because the default behavior for binding is to search the
> local namespace first. The statement allows encapsulated code to
> rebind variables outside of the local scope besides the global
> (module) scope.
>
> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike to those listed in a
> global statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing
> scope (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be
> determined unambiguously).
>
> Names listed in a nonlocal statement must not collide with pre-
> existing bindings in the local scope

Answer (score 0):

```
global x

def outer():

    x="global"

    def inner():
        nonlocal x
        x="nonlocal"

    def inner2():
        x="local"

inner2()

print(x)

inner()

print(x)

outer()
```

```
Output:

global

nonlocal
```