# Is there a common name for variables which are not local and not global?

Tags: terminology

According to Wikipedia

> a global variable is a variable with global scope, meaning that it is
> visible (hence accessible) throughout the program

What do we call a variable which is not local to any function but not accessible throughout the program, only to the functions declared in the same unit as the variable, where a unit can be a file, module or a class depending on the language?

**Edit**: Examples would be a static variable declared at file scope in C, a private static variable in Java or a non-exported variable with module scope in Oberon.

Comment: nonlocal? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33211272/10699612 ; The term will vary among different technologies and languages.

Comment: That strategy is called dependency injection and it is a valid technique but we don't have a specific name for it. If it is created in a specific function and given to other functions using arguments, It counts as a local variable. Otherwise it's a global variable.

Comment: In python they are called global variables... this question is too broad when language agnostic.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні I think that is exactly the problem; for instance when someone says "avoid global variables", what do they actually mean? Sometimes a global variable is defined as a variable which is accessible everywhere and sometimes it's defined (more generally) as a variable which is not local to a function.

Comment: That is indeed a problem, fixed by avoiding pointlessly general statements (ones that claim to apply to all technologies). I'm not sure this question will fix that. Only more specific communication (narrower context or more words) will help.

Comment: @M.Elghamry A non-local variable could also mean a variable from an enclosing function scope in a language which supports nested functions like Pascal, so that won't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

If the scope of the variable is not known, it is called a [free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variable).

Otherwise the non-local variables are typically named by the scope where they were declared, i.e. "global variable", "module(-scoped) variable", "file-scoped variable", "class(-scoped) variable" or whatever else units your language has.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a common name for variables which are not local and not global?

From my experience, I'd say "probably not".

In C, a static variable which is not declared `extern` is visible only in the same compilation unit. Because C compilation units hare files, we say it has "file scope".

In Swift, the equivalent to C file scope is "file private" (using the `fileprivate` key word). But, in Swift there's another level between the file and "global" scope. A variable can be declared `internal` which means accessible to anything else in the same module.

Other languages will have different terminology and different rules. For example, Java Has one class per file, so anything in the class (except function local variables) is visible to anything else in the same file. However, you can also have public variables and functions that are visible to anything in the program and also (I think - it's been a long time) package level visibility.