# How to access variables in function inside a function

Tags: python

I am trying to run following code in Python3.4, but I am getting error.

```
def checknumner():
    i = 0
    print("checknumber called...")
    def is_even():
        print("is_even called...")
        global i
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print("Even: ", i)
        else:
            print("Odd: ", i)
        i += 1
    return is_even

c = checknumner()
print(c())
print(c())
print(c())
```

I am not able to access variable "i" in sub function.

When I comment out "global i" statment

```
D:\Study\Python>python generator_without_generator.py checknumber called... is_even called... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "generator_without_generator.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(c())   File "generator_without_generator.py", line 16, in is_even
    if i % 2 == 0: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

When I add "global i" statment

```
D:\Study\Python>python generator_without_generator.py checknumber called... is_even called... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "generator_without_generator.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(c())   File "generator_without_generator.py", line 16, in is_even
    if i % 2 == 0: NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3 (and it looks like you are), there's an amazing way to tackle this issue:

```
def function():
    i = 0
    def another_function():
        nonlocal i 
        # use 'i' here
```

Here, `i` isn't global as it would've been defined outside *both functions* otherwise. It also isn't local to `another_function` as it's defined outside it. So, it's *non local*.

More info about `nonlocal`:

- [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)
- [Python 3.6 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal)
- [Quick guide about `nonlocal` in Python 3](https://www.smallsurething.com/a-quick-guide-to-nonlocal-in-python-3/)

Comment: Why is `nonlocal` at all necessary? Even in your example, this is just a closure, meaning the inner function _has_ access to the variables defined in the outer function.

Comment: EDIT: It's the line `i += 1` that causes the reference error, but irregardless, `i` never gets increased even on repetitive calls with the given code, and `i` is still accessible via the closure's scope.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi the value of "I" increments and using nonlocal it works perfectly.