# values arguments in pdg

Tags: python, debugging

I have created a simple function on python and make some tests with the debugger to see how it works.

I wanted to print the value of a variable (`raiz`):

```
(dbg) p raiz
```

But it says that it's not defined. Why is this? Here is my code:

```
import math
def funcion(sen):
    raiz = math.sqrt(sen)
    return "the sqrt of " + repr(sen) + 'is ' + repr(raiz)

print (funcion(38))

import pudb;
pudb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with [Scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

The place that variables are defined is important, and defining them in certain places will cause them to disappear elsewhere. Here is an example:

```
# PLEASE NOTE: This code will fail.
a = "Hello"

def my_func():
   b = "Hello" # Declare a variable 'b', but only in this scope, in other words this function.

my_func()

print(a) # Works, since a is in the same scope.
print(b) # Fails, since b was defined inside a different scope, and discarded later.
```

Since, in your example, `raiz` was declared inside the function `funcion`, Python discarded it after `funcion` was called. If you put the line:

```
raiz = 0
```

before your function definition, the function would simply update the variable, so there would be no issue, since the scope would be the same as where the `print` statement occurs.

**tl;dr**: The variable `raiz` was declared only in `funcion`, so it was discarded afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is declared inside the function, not outside, so the code can't see it.

If you need to set value for outside variable, mark it with `global` keyword (which is a bad practice):

```
import math

raiz = None

def funcion(sen):
    nonlocal raiz
    raiz = math.sqrt(sen)
    return "the sqrt of " + repr(sen) + 'is ' + repr(raiz)

funcion(38)
print (raiz)
```

Also you can use [`nonlocal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1261961/213550) keyword, but for this case it would fail with:

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'raiz' found
```

You can find a tutorial about local, nonlocal and global keywords [here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php).