# How to use nonlocal statement with several inner functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-nonlocal

Might someone explain me why this function is not working ? Shouldn't the "nonlocal" statement makes `x` understandable in `g`, and therefore in `h` ?

```
def f():
    def g():
        nonlocal x
        x= 1
    def h():
        print(x)


>>> SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found
```

Edit : I used nonlocal in order not to define `x` anywhere else than in `g()` : I have to define several variables in my code, and want to do it in a function `init_var()`. For lisibility, I want to avoid declaring them in my main function. Is there a way to adapt the previous code for this aim ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement / keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

> Names listed in a `nonlocal` statement, unlike those listed in a `global` statement, must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be determined unambiguously).

Your `x` is not pre-existing at the point of `nonlocal`. Try `x = None` just before `def g():` to create a binding for `nonlocal` to refer to.

The ambiguity problem stated by the docs are easy to see here:

```
def f():
    def g():
        def h():
            def i():
                def j():
                    nonlocal x
```

Which functions should have access to `x`, and which shouldn't? On the other hand, here it is clear:

```
def f():
    def g():
        def h():
            x = None
            def i():
                def j():
                    nonlocal x
```

In this case, `f` and `g` don't know `x`, while `h`, `i` and `j` do.

Comment: One might add that the global namespace does not count as an enclosing scope here. Putting `x = None` outside of function `f` will fail.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear answer. I edited my question, because I want to know if there is a way to avoid this `x = None` declaration, (for the lisibility of the code)

Comment: I can't think of a way. Setting up a dictionary or an object with values is much easier; setting up individual variables is hard because they are checked by static analysis.

Comment: Another reason why this is required is that Python 3.x implements non-global scopes in a way that's more like a `namedtuple` than a `dict` (such that `locals()` has to create a new `dict` on the fly). Writing `nonlocal x` and then `x = 1` can't create a name that didn't already exist in the appropriate enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether what you are trying really helps readability. If you want to to structure your code, you might want to consider using a class and (instance) attributes. That being said, if you want to avoid multiple assignment lines, you can use attributes of the outer function:

```
>>> def f():
...   def g():
...     f.a = 5
...   def h():
...     print(f.a)
...   g()
...   h()
... 
>>> f()
5
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! Just a question : you have answered the second question, and @Amadan the first, is it possible to concatenate both answers so I can accept the answer ?