# Python non-local variables

Tags: python, variables

Isn't it supposed to return 'inner: nonlocal' and 'outer: local'?? Can someone explain what's happening, thanks.

```
>>>>def outer():
        x = 'local'
        def inner():
            nonlocal x
            x='nonlocal'
            print('inner:',x)
        inner()
        print('outer:',x)

>>>outer()
 inner: nonlocal
 outer: nonlocal
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)

Comment: The [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) statement causes the listed identifiers(in this case its `x`) to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding globals

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `x` to `'nonlocal'` by calling `inner()`. Thus, `x` is set to `'nonlocal'` no matter where you try to print it from within `outer()`. Put the print statement *before* the call to `inner()` and it will work.

Comment: That is only because the `nonlocal` statement is used.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Did I imply anything else?

Comment: Sorry, I misphrased my comment. While your answer is correct, I think the OP is asking why the `x` set in the scope of `inner()` is visible in `outer()`, and this is because of the `nonlocal x` statement in `inner()`.  (as addressed by the other answer).

Answer (score 1):

See [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) link for information on `non-local`.

> The nonlocal statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope excluding globals. This is important because the default behavior for binding is to search the local namespace first. The statement allows encapsulated code to rebind variables outside of the local scope besides the global (module) scope.

**In short, it lets you assign values to a variable in an outer (but non-global) scope.**

If you remove the keyword `nonlocal` and try your program, you will observe:

```
inner: nonlocal
outer: local
```

Program:

```
def outer():
    x = 'local'
    def inner():
        x='nonlocal'
        print('inner:', x)
    inner()
    print('outer:', x)


outer()
```