# Why doesn't co_varnames return list of all the variable names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Why the result of below snippets are different?

```
def Foo():
  i = 0
  def Bar():
    nonlocal i
    i = 1
  return Bar()

print(Foo.__code__.co_varnames)

# it will print: ('Bar',)
```

```
def Foo():
  i = 0
  def Bar():
    i = 1
  return Bar()

print(Foo.__code__.co_varnames)

# it will print: ('i', 'Bar',)
```

As you see, the results are different and I don't know why they are different.

Comment: ```nonlocal i``` refers to ```i``` in ```Foo``` (outer scope, not global though). Explained in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit subtle. While `co_varnames` should give you all *local* variables, in this case,`i` is actually a free variable in `Bar`, so it is in `Bar`'s *closure*.

Notice what happens when we dissasemble the bytecode:

```
In [2]: def Foo():
   ...:   i = 0
   ...:   def Bar():
   ...:     nonlocal i
   ...:     i = 1
   ...:   return Bar()
   ...:

In [3]: Foo.__code__.co_varnames
Out[3]: ('Bar',)


In [4]: import dis

In [5]: dis.dis(Foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (i)

  3           4 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (i)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object Bar at 0x101072be0, file "<ipython-input-4-a3a062461e32>", line 3>)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Foo.<locals>.Bar')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            8 (closure)
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (Bar)

  6          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (Bar)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             20 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object Bar at 0x101072be0, file "<ipython-input-4-a3a062461e32>", line 3>:
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (i)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice, the opcode is `STORE_DEREF` not `STORE_FAST`. So, consider:

```
In [9]: def Foo():
   ...:   i = 0
   ...:   def Bar():
   ...:     nonlocal i
   ...:     i = 1
   ...:   return Bar
   ...:

In [10]: bar = Foo()

In [11]: bar.__closure__
Out[11]: (<cell at 0x1040a7940: int object at 0x100980bc0>,)
```

Since it is referenced in a nested function, this will be available in `co_cellvars`:

```
In [12]: foo_code = Foo.__code__

In [13]: foo_code.co_cellvars
Out[13]: ('i',)
```

This is explained in the data-model [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for internal types:

> `co_varnames` is a tuple containing the
>   names of the local variables (starting with the argument names);
>   `co_cellvars` is a tuple **containing the names of local variables that
>   are referenced by nested functions**; `co_freevars` is a tuple containing
>   the names of free variables...

So to get *all local variables* you need:

```
In [16]: Foo.__code__.co_varnames + Foo.__code__.co_cellvars
Out[16]: ('Bar', 'i')
```