# python: variable value is not changing

Tags: python

I have defined a variable on initialization, now if I`m trying to change the value it does not change.

```
File=""

def pathValue():
    if File:
        print("file path: " + File)
    else:
        File = "abc.txt"
        print("file path: " + File)

pathValue()
```

Above is my sample code. It should change the value of the 'File' variable to 'abc.txt' but it's not working. Instead, it shows like this,

```
file path:
```

if the variable is empty then how can it bypass the if-condition?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the question! It would be a big help if you told us a little about how you've already tried to fix the issue and why that didn't work. Regardless, the issue is that, within `pathValue`, Python is treating `File` as a local variable. To fix it, add `nonlocal File` as the first line to `pathValue`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)

Comment: @Quelklef I think `global` is more relevant here than `nonlocal` .

Comment: @VishalSingh Yeah, you're right. Looks like `nonlocal` can't reach into the global context (dunno why). I can't edit my original comment, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get an error message instead, as I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `File` is out of scope for the function `pathValue()`, either declare it inside the function, :

```
def pathValue():
    File=""
    if File:
        print("file path: " + File)
    else:
        File = "abc.txt"
        print("file path: " + File)

pathValue()
```

or make it a global variable :

```
File=""

def pathValue():
    global File
    if File:
        print("file path: " + File)
    else:
        File = "abc.txt"
        print("file path: " + File)

pathValue()
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I've used global keyword but the this is 'File' is used by two other functions and I forgot to use global in all functions. Silly mistake, but thank you again

Answer (score 3):

You may add `global File` as the first line of your function so python would treat `File` as a global and not as a local variable.