# Python function inside function access to a global variable

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function `func1()` inside which I want to do a parallel job using multi-threading. I am defining another function inside that function called `func_thread()` to access some local variables and avoid passing them to the thread function. However, for all those variables that are read-only, I do not have any problem. But, for the output value (`x` here which all threads are adding some value to `x`) I have trouble.

In this case I receive `x referenced before assignment` error.

```py
def func1():
    lc = threading.Lock()
    x = np.zeros((100,100))
    def func_thread():
        lc.acquire()
        x = x + np.random.random((100,100))
        lc.release()
```

And in this case, I receive `global variable x is not defined` error!

```py
def func1():
    x = np.zeros((100,100))
    def func_thread():
        global x
        x = x + np.random.random((100,100))
```

Comment: Just call `func_thread`  with `x`, won't you?

Comment: You want `nonlocal`, not `global`. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement). Not sure if that counts as a duplicate though.

Comment: Declare both x as global,or the inner one as nonlocal.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `nonlocal` worked, thanks. Please write it as an answer so that I can accept it. The link you sent was more general than my question but covers my answer as well.

Comment: Please be aware that neither `a += b` nor `a = a + b` are atomic. They are not threadsafe even with the Gil, and introduce a subtle race condition.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I am using thread locks

Comment: @aminrd Your question has been closed, so I'm unable to answer it. If anyone has a similar question as you though, the links here should help them (although I think the chosen dupe, while a good read, is a little broad).