# Would you please explain where does b comes come?

Tags: python, function

I just don't understand, we never define param b in the inner function, but why would the inner function accept a+b without error?

```
def test(a):
    def add(b):
        nonlocal a
        a += 1
        return a+b
    return add


func = test(4)
print(func(4))
```

the above function comes from here: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-functions-exercise-19.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening in this function:

- Line 1 creates `test()`, which is a closure factory function. This means that it creates a new closure each time it’s called and then returns **the closure** to the caller.
- Line 2 defines `add()`, which is an inner function that takes a single argument, base, and returns **the result of the expression** `a*b`.
- Line 6 returns `add()` as a **function object**, without calling it.

The question now is where does `add()` get the value of `a` from? This is where the closure comes into play. `add()` gets the value of `a` from the outer function, `test()`. Here’s what Python does when you call `test()` in line 9:

- Define a new instance of `add()`, which takes a single argument base.
- Take a snapshot of the surrounding state of `add()`, which includes
  `a` with its current value (in line 9 you are defining it as `a = 4`).
- Return `add()` along with its whole surrounding state.

This way, when you call the instance of `add()` returned by `test()` in line 10, you’ll see that the function remembers the value of `a`! So what you have is the previously assigned value of `a = 4` (line 9), and the newly passed argument - the value of `b = 4` (line 10).

Hope this helps to clarify!

Answer (score 1):

The way how it is written, is a typical way to access a function defined within a function. This is done by returning the desired function when the main function is called. For instance: see below your code with two functions defined within function TEST() and one of them is called:

```
def test(a):
    def times(b):
        nonlocal a
        return a*b
    def add(b):
        nonlocal a
        a += 1
        return a+b
    return times


func = test(4) print(func(4))
```

in this case the ouput is 16.

Answer (score -1):

You're passing `b` in this call: `func(4)`.

To be clear, `func` is `add`.

Answer (score -1):

`test` will create and return a function with one callee that adds one to a and add it to the callee