# Access a variable from a function in a function within the first

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, asynchronous

I want to add 1 to `variable` in another function which happens to be within that function.
This is my code and I've obviously tried with and without the `global`:

```
async def start():
    variable = 0
    async def begin():
        #global variable
        variable += 1
    await begin()
```

I would need a solution that does not involve function arguments or global variables out of the `start()` function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using `async` but did you try `nonlocal` instead of `global`?

Comment: `I would need a solution that does not involve function arguments` why tho

Comment: It's a callback function.

Comment: No Tomerikoo I haven't. Will now research that, thank you.

Comment: [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1261875/6045800)

Comment: It seems like a great solution. Didn't know nonlocal was a thing. Thank you for helping me and teaching me this.